# Como funcionam protótipos em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, orientação-a-objetos, protótipo

Parece-me que o conceito de protótipo é fundamental em JavaScript e inclusive em vários lugares tenho lido que é um de seus pontos fortes. Entretanto, esse não parece um conceito tão simples de entender para quem vem de outras linguagens.

Assim, pergunto: como funcionam protótipos em JavaScript?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

### A cadeia de protótipos

É bem simples na verdade. Cada objeto possui uma referência a um *protótipo*, que é sempre outro objeto, ou `null`. Esse objeto, por sua vez, também possui um protótipo. Forma-se então uma *cadeia de protótipos*.

E para que serve isso? O funcionamento é semelhante ao conceito de herança. Considere o seguinte exemplo: você tem um objeto que representa um veículo, vamos chamá-lo de `veiculo`. Suponha ainda outros dois outros objetos, `carro` e `onibus`, que tenham `veiculo` como protótipo. E suponha que `veiculo` possua um método `buzinar`. A cadeia de protótipos torna possível invocar esse método em `carro` e `onibus`:

```
carro.buzinar();
onibus.buzinar();
```

E como isso funciona? Ao invocar o método, o interpretador verifica se o objeto em questão (`carro` ou `onibus`) possui um método com esse nome. Neste caso, os objetos não possuem esse método. Então o interpretador verifica se o *protótipo* de cada objeto possui o método, e neste caso ele encontra e invoca o método `buzinar`. Caso o método não fosse encontrado, o interpretador continuaria a verificação subindo na cadeia de protótipos, até encontrar o método ou propriedade desejado, ou até chegar a um objeto que possua `null` como protótipo.

É importante saber que essa invocação funciona como se o método pertencesse ao próprio objeto; ou seja, qualquer referência a `this` dentro do método `buzinar` irá apontar para `carro` ou `onibus` neste exemplo.

### Atribuição de protótipo

A linguagem não oferece nenhuma maneira oficial de se trocar o protótipo de um objeto *on-the-fly*. O protótipo é atribuído somente no momento da criação do objeto, e isso pode ser feito de duas maneiras.

#### 1. Atribuição via construtor

Toda função possui uma proprieade chamada `prototype` (funções são objetos em JavaScript, portanto podem possuir propriedades). Quando uma função é invocada como construtor, é criado um novo objeto cujo protótipo é o valor da propriedade `prototype` da função. Por exemplo:

```
function Veiculo() {}
Veiculo.prototype.buzinar = function() {
    alert('Fom');
}
var carro = new Veiculo(); // invocação como construtor
carro.buzinar();           // dispara o alert
```

#### 2. Atribuição direta

A partir do ECMAScript 5, a linguagem oferece outra maneira de se criar um objeto com determinado protótipo, a função `Object.create`. Repare que ela é um método *do construtor* `Object`, portanto pode ser considerada um método estático. O que essa função faz é criar um novo objeto cujo protótipo é o que tiver sido passado como primeiro argumento:

```
var veiculo = {
    buzinar: function() {
        alert('Fom');
    }
};
var carro = Object.create(veiculo); // veiculo será o protótipo de carro
carro.buzinar();                    // dispara o alert
```

#### 3. Atribuição *on-the-fly*

Oficialmente, JavaScript não permite alterar o protótipo de objetos já existentes, porém as principais implementações (incluindo todos os browsers que eu conheço) permitem isso por meio da propriedade não-padrão `__proto__`. Usando essa propriedade é possível fazer algo assim:

```
var veiculo = {
    buzinar: function() {
        alert('Fom');
    }
};
var carro = {};             // carro ganha protótipo padrão (Object.prototype)
carro.__proto__ = veiculo;  // troca protótipo
carro.buzinar();            // dispara o alert
```

### Notas sobre a especificação

A explicação acima é bem informal, e similar ao que a especificação da linguagem [descreve](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.2.1), também informalmente. Porém a descrição contida na especificação pode parecer um pouco confusa, pois há duas coisas chamadas "prototype": a [propriedade **`prototype`** dos objetos do tipo função](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.5), e o [[[Prototype]]](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.6.2), que é o nome oficial da propriedade *interna* dos objetos. Quando a especificação usa o termo *prototype* sem formatação de código nem colchetes, refere-se geralmente ao [[Prototype]], da mesma maneira que usei o termo *protótipo* na descrição acima.

No que diz respeito ao acesso à cadeia de protótipos, o ponto crucial na especificação é a função interna [[[GetProperty]]](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.12.2), invocada quando você tenta acessar uma propriedade de um objeto. Trata-se de uma função recursiva, que retorna a propriedade solicitada de determinado objeto, esteja ela no próprio objeto ou em um dos membros de sua cadeia de protótipos.

Comment: Com o ES6, o prototype tornou-se obsoleto?

Comment: Não, de maneira alguma! A nova sintaxe com `class` é açúcar sintático, o protótipo é que continua fazendo tudo funcionar.

Comment: @bfavaretto, Protótipo é uma maneira de reutilizar métodos em outros objetos?

Comment: @felipecardozo Sim, os métodos compartilhados pertencem ao protótipo e podem ser utilizados por qualquer objeto que faça parte da cadeia de protótipos.

Comment: @bfavaretto, valeu amigo!

Comment: Em relação a este trecho: "[...] não permite alterar o protótipo de objetos já existentes [...]", acho que convém alterar, uma vez que (relativamente) recentemente foram introduzidos os métodos `Object.setPrototypeOf` e `Reflect.setPrototypeOf`. A operação `[[Set]]` em `__proto__` também já foi [estandardizada no anexo B da especificação](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-set-object.prototype.__proto__). Eu até ia editar, mas acabei achando melhor comentar mesmo. :P   (pode apagar este comentário depois)

Comment: Obrigado @LuizFelipe. Já pensei várias vezes em atualizar esta resposta, mas ando sem tempo. Por enquanto fica o seu comentário rs.