# Qual a diferença entre Object.create ou new Object() em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, característica-linguagem, objetos

Estou passando por uma dúvida técnica em JavaScript:

- Qual a diferença entre `Object.create` e `new Object()`?
- Quais os casos em que tenho que adotar um ao invés do outro?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O método [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) recebe parâmetros. O primeiro é obrigatório e será usado como [protótipo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype) do novo objeto. O segundo é um mapa de propriedades com as quais objeto já "nasce".

Já `new Object()` é uma forma mais longa e não recomendada de se dizer `{}`.

As três linhas de código abaixo são equivalentes:

```
let a = {}; // legal
let b = new Object(); // coisa de dinossauros pedantes

let c = Object.create(null); // isso pode ser útil se ao invés de nulo
                             //você passar um parâmetro.
```

O método `create` pode ser bastante útil se você usar alguma lógica mais complexa para criar seus objetos. Novamente, os dois trechos de código abaixo são equivalentes:

```
// forma verbosa
let foo = {};
foo.prototype = Array;

let bar = {nome: "john", idade: 21};

for (let propriedade in bar) {
    foo[propriedade] = bar[propriedade];
}

// forma curta
let foo = Object.create(Array, {nome: "john", idade: 21});
```

Comment: Nossa, eu uso new Object().... Me senti ofendido :p.

Comment: Coia de dinossauros pedantes foi ótimo. `foo.prototype = Array` não tem nem direito a apelação, vai direto para a forca. Estou sem tempo para elaborar uma resposta, mas existem algumas particularidades de cada método, por exemplo, com `Object.create` você pode "herdar" as propriedades de um objeto sem herdar seu protótipo, bem como fazer uma série de coisas interessantes (e.g., `mixin`). Para mais detalhes: [MDN - Object.create()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create).

Comment: Outra referência interessante: [Adobe Developer Connection - JavaScript object creation: Learning to live without "new"](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/html5/articles/javascript-object-creation.html)

Comment: Oi! A sua resposta está com _vários_ detalhes incorretos e/ou pouco precisos. Irei destacá-los aqui: 1) O segundo argumento de `Object.assign` **não** serve para "definir as propriedades com as quais objeto já nasce", mas sim define os _descritores de propriedade_ iniciais. 2) `Object.assign(null)` não é o mesmo que `{}` ou `new Object` (como o primeiro exemplo de código incorretamente sugere). 3) O segundo exemplo de código está incorreto, uma vez que a propriedade `prototype` **não** define um protótipo, mas sim é uma propriedade especial de construtores que será atribuída ao protótipo [...]

Comment: do objeto durante a instanciação. Utilize a (não recomendada) propriedade `__proto__` para isso ou métodos como `Reflect.setPrototypeOf` ou `Object.setPrototypeOf` para isso. Além disso, como disse anteriormente, o segundo argumento de `Object.assign` não define propriedades iniciais, mas sim os descritores de propriedade iniciais, de modo que torna isto incorreto: `Object.create(Array, {nome: "john", idade: 21})`. Procurei detalhar um pouco mais [na resposta que escrevi](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/494957/69296).

Answer (score 6):

#### TL;DR

Na *grande maioria* das vezes, para se criar um objeto em JavaScript, basta fazer algo assim:

```
const myObject = {
  // ...
};
```

De modo que, terá sido criado um novo objeto `myObject` cujo [protótipo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15239/69296) aponta para [`Object.prototype`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object#instance_methods). O `{}` (forma literal), é análogo a se utilizar `new Object()` ou `Object()`. Apesar dessa equivalência, prefira sempre utilizar `{}`.

Já a função **[`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create)**, *diferentemente* do demonstrado anteriormente, deverá ser utilizada quando:

- For necessário definir um [protótipo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15239/69296) diferente ao objeto a ser criado; e/ou:
- For necessário definir [descritores de propriedade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/478411/69296) iniciais do objeto a ser criado (não confundir com propriedades).

Portanto, ao se criar um objeto com `{}`, `new Object()` ou `Object()`, limita-se a um novo objeto cujo protótipo é sempre [`Object.prototype`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/478411/69296). A função `Object.create` permite que sejam criados objetos com um protótipo diferente e/ou propriedades com descritores definidos com maior granularidade.

---

## Primeiro argumento de `Object.create`

O primeiro argumento de `Object.create` é útil para definir um "protótipo customizado" na criação de um objeto. Então, no exemplo abaixo:

```
const customPrototype = {}; // Qualquer objeto.

const obj = Object.create(customPrototype);
```

O objeto `obj` terá como protótipo o objeto `customPrototype`, que foi passado no primeiro argumento da função. Então a avaliação de `Reflect.getPrototypeOf(obj) === customPrototype` resultaria em verdadeiro.

É, de certo modo, o mesmo que isto:

```
const customPrototype = {}; // Qualquer objeto.

const obj = {};
Reflect.setPrototypeOf(obj, customPrototype);
```

A desvantagem de redefinir o protótipo após o objeto ter sido criado é que os atuasi interpretadores de JavaScript não possuem otimizações para a redefinição prototípica, uma vez que é uma operação pouco usual e relativamente custosa (toda a cadeia de protótipos do objeto será alterada). Portanto, é mais indicado definir o protótipo customizado durante a *criação* do objeto do que fazer isso uma vez que o objeto já tenha sido criado. Por isso existe o primeiro argumento de `Object.create`.

## Segundo argumento de `Object.create`

O segundo argumento de `Object.create` define os **descritores de propriedade** que o objeto a ser criado possuirá.

Ao contrário do inúmeras pessoas pensam, o segundo argumento de `Object.create` não serve para definir propriedades iniciais para um objeto, mas sim definir os **descritores de propriedades** iniciais que o objeto irá assumir. Sobre descritores e atributos de propriedades, é um assunto extenso que dá uma resposta por si só. Trato em mais detalhes sobre eles em [O que são e como funcionam os descritores e atributos de propriedade do JavaScript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/478411/69296).

Então, um exemplo (criando um novo objeto cujo protótipo é `null` e com os dados descritores de propriedades):

```js
const obj = Object.create(null, {
  name: {
    value: 'Bob',
    writable: false,
    enumerable: false,
    configurable: false
  },
  age: {
    value: 50,
    writable: false,
    enumerable: false,
    configurable: false
  }
});

console.log(obj);
console.log(Object.keys(obj));

console.log('---\nAs propriedades estão aqui!');

// As propriedades estão lá! Só não podem ser enumeradas
// normalmente porque o atributo `enumerable` de cada
// propriedade foi definido, na criação, como `false`.
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj));
console.log(obj.name);
console.log(obj.age);
```

Desse modo, não é correto fazer isto:

```
// Este código não é válido.
const obj = Object.create(null, {
  name: 'Bob',
  age: 50
});
```

Como o segundo argumento não contém *descritor(es) de propriedade* válido(s), o seguinte erro será lançado:

> ```
> Uncaught TypeError: Property description must be an object
> ```

É pouco intuitivo e menos útil. Seria muito mais interessante utilizar o segundo argumento de `Object.create` para definir as **propriedades** (não confundir com *descritor de propriedade*) a serem assumidas pelo objeto durante a sua criação. Se isso for necessário, pode-se combinar `Object.create` com `Object.assign`:

```js
// Criaremos um objeto cujo protótipo é `null`
// E as propriedades definidas inicialmente são `name` e `age`:
const obj = Object.assign(Object.create(null), {
  name: 'Bob',
  age: 50
});

console.log(obj); //=> { name: "Bob", age: 50 }
console.log(Reflect.getPrototypeOf(obj)); //=> null
```

Mais detalhes sobre o `Object.assign` **[nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/477895/69296)** ou na [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).

A título de curiosidade, além de `Object.create`, as funções [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) e [`Object.defineProperties`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties) também podem ser utilizadas para definir propriedades através da descrição de propriedades em um objeto. A diferença é que `Object.create` faz na criação e, as duas últimas, uma vez que o objeto já tenha sido criado.

## Considerações sobre `{}`, `Object()` e `new Object()`

São equivalentes:

```
1 | const a = {};
2 | const b = new Object();
3 | const c = Object();
```

Na linha 1, cria-se um objeto a partir da notação literal. Na linha 2, cria-se um objeto a partir da instanciação do construtor `Object`. Na linha 3, cria-se um objeto a partir da invocação de `Object`. Todos os três criarão um novo objeto cujo protótipo é [`Object.prototype`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/478411/69296).

Demonstração:

```js
const a = {};
const b = new Object();
const c = Object();

console.log(Reflect.getPrototypeOf(a) === Object.prototype); //=> true
console.log(Reflect.getPrototypeOf(b) === Object.prototype); //=> true
console.log(Reflect.getPrototypeOf(c) === Object.prototype); //=> true
```

Então, **não** é correto dizer que as três formas acima são equivalentes à `Object.create(null)`, uma vez que os protótipos são diferentes.

Ao utilizar `Object.create(null)`, cria-se um novo objeto no qual `null` é o protótipo. Já utilizar `{}`, `Object()` ou `new Object()` são três formas *equivalentes* de se criar um novo objeto no qual `Object.prototype` é o protótipo.

No entanto, `Object.create(Object.prototype)` é, sim, equivalente às três formas em questão.

---

São detalhes sutis, mas que fazem diferença. Esta [outra excelente respsota](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/15247/69296) dá mais detalhes sobre a cadeia de protótipos, que é um conceito fundamental para entender esta resposta sobre `Object.create`.

Além disso, a leitura [sobre descritores de propriedades](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/478411/69296) é, também, importante para entender plenamente o funcionamento de `Object.create`.