# O que é um Array-Like?

Tags: javascript, array

Um dado string é um array-like, já um dado number não o é. Já seus respectivos objetos são array-likes (os objetos em si), né? Um objeto declarado, um Objeto DOM também é um arraylike, correto? Tudo é array-like menos dados number boolean e operadores. Tudo isso é muito confuso para mim.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Em JavaScript (e potencialmente outras linguagens, mas não me recordo de nenhuma) existe um tipo de dado `Array` que possui uma propriedade `length` (indicando seu tamanho), a capacidade de ter seus elementos individuais acessados por índices numérios (`x[0]`), e vários outros métodos pertencentes ao tipo.

Entretanto, exceto por alguns pequenos detalhes (mais sobre isso adiante), não há diferença significativa entre um array e um objeto "normal". Se você criar um objeto do tipo:

```js
var objeto = { "0":"foo", "1":"bar", "2":"baz", length:3 };
```

Você pode usá-lo em muitas situações como se ele fosse um array nativo:

```js
for ( var i = 0 ; i < objeto.length ; i++ )
    console.log(objeto[i]);
```

O que você **não pode** fazer é usar métodos nativos de `Array` - já que esse objeto não possui esse tipo como protótipo (por padrão - se você quiser, você pode dar esse protótipo a ele):

```js
objeto.forEach(function() { ... }); // undefined não é um método
```

Outra diferença é que em um array, adicionar novos elementos atualiza sua propriedade `length` automaticamente, enquanto num objeto comum isso não acontece:

```js
var arr = [];
$("#saida").append("<p>" + arr.length + "</p>");
arr[0] = 10;
$("#saida").append("<p>" + arr.length + "</p>");

var obj = { length: 0 };
$("#saida").append("<p>" + obj.length + "</p>");
obj[0] = 10;
$("#saida").append("<p>" + obj.length + "</p>");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="saida"></div>
```

Por não haver diferença significativa, é muito comum uma biblioteca JavaScript permitir que os programadores usem seus objetos como se fossem arrays, mesmo quando é inconveniente usar um array "de verdade". Nesse caso, diz-se que o objeto é "parecido com um array", ou em inglês *"array-like"*. O melhor exemplo que eu tenho de um *array-like* é o "objeto jQuery":

```js
var ps = $("p"); // Selecionei todos os elementos p
ps.html("foo"); // O retorno é um objeto jQuery, com suas próprias funções

for ( var i = 0 ; i < ps.length ; i++ ) // Mas também posso usá-lo como se fosse um array
    ps[i].innerHTML = "foo";
```

Saber se um objeto é array ou *array-like* só é importante quando o mesmo é usado de uma forma específica para arrays. Muitas vezes, para permitir uma gama maior de valores de entrada (i.e. sem limitar a objetos do tipo `Array`) se opta por programar de uma forma que funcione tanto para arrays quanto *array-likes*. O `for` acima foi um exemplo. Outro seria o uso das funções de `Array` referenciadas explicitamente no seu protótipo:

```js
Array.prototype.forEach.call(objeto, function() { ... }); // Funciona em ambos os casos
```

Ou, para acrescentar um elemento e garantir que o `length` seja atualizado:

```js
var objeto = { length:0 };
Array.prototype.push.call(objeto, 10); // Depois dessa chamada, length é 1
```

P.S. Também é bom frisar que em JavaScript todas as propriedades são textuais. Mesmo num objeto do tipo `Array`, quando você faz:

```js
var arr = [1,2,3];
arr[1] = 4;
```

Internamente isso é representado como se fosse:

```js
var arr = Object.create(Array.prototype, { "0":1, "1":2, "2":3, "length":3 });
arr["1"] = 4;
```

Outras linguagens podem ter implementações diferentes, e considerações diferentes em relação ao que é ou não um *array-like* (ou mesmo não permitir *array-likes* em absoluto). Formalmente falando, para um objeto ser considerado *X-like* ele deve possuir uma interface implícita que é compatível, até certo ponto, com o tipo "X". Ou seja, ainda que ele não pertença à classe, e essa classe não possua um contrato explícito, esse objeto ainda cumpra suficientemente o seu contrato implícito para poder ser usado na prática como uma instância daquele tipo.

Desnecessário dizer, esse conceito só faz sentido em linguagens com tipagem dinâmica ou *duck-typing* - se a tipagem é estática, a única coisa que pode ser usada no lugar de um array é um subtipo de array (que, pela relação de herança "é um" array, não "se parece com" um array).

Comment: O que é protótipo?

Comment: @ropbla9 Para entender protótipos (e herança prototípica), sugiro a pergunta ["Como funcionam protótipos em JavaScript?"](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15239/215) (que eu saiba, JS é a única linguagem popular que usa esse tipo de orientação por objetos). Sobre seu comentário anterior, string é array-like sim, pois possui `length` e seus caracteres (substrings, na verdade) são acessados por índice numérico. Já um objeto qualquer não seria - pois é necessário a propriedade `length` no mínimo (e se o objeto não é usado de forma sequencial, ele não *funciona* como array-like).

Comment: Então todo objeto do JS não é array-like? Até mesmo o Array, sendo arraylike apenas o seu dado primitivo (array)? Só objetos declarados e DOM são array-likes? correto?

Comment: Amigo, tenho extrema necessidade de falar contigo por chat. Seria possível?

Comment: @ropbla9 Ainda está aí? Eu estava offline e não vi sua resposta, foi mal! Quanto ao seu comentário, ser ou não *array-like* é mais uma questão de funcionalidade: se um objeto implementa uma lista, mas o faz por meio de um encadeamento (ex.: `{car:1, cdr:{ car:2, cdr:{ car:3, cdr:null }}}`) não dá pra acessar esse objeto usando índices. Se ele usa outra coisa em vez de `length` (ex.: `{"0":1, "1":2, "2": 3, tamanho:3}`) uma função que foi feita esperando um array não vai funcionar nele. Etc. Ser *array-like* significa "se eu passar ele pra uma função que espera um array, vai funcionar". Só.

Comment: Estudo JS há 5 meses e esses conceitos ainda são complexos para mim (primeiro contato com programação). Quero muito aprender mais sobre manipulação de DOM, sei q seria mais mole com JQ, mas quero aprender JS puro. Tava querendo comprar o curso de JS completo do DevMedia. O que você acha?

Comment: Acho difícil opinar, eu não conheço esse curso, e como faz tempo que aprendi JS (aliás, "fui aprendendo" aos poucos...) não sei de material bom e atualizado. Já verificou na [wiki de tag do JavaScript](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info)? No final tem algumas recomendações de livros e material online, feitas por outros usuários.