# Objetos são semelhantes a arrays?

Tags: javascript, array, objetos

Objetos são *arrays* em JavaSscript? Eu tenho dificuldades em entender como isso é possível:

```
var obj = {
   title: 'some value'
}
console.log(obj['title']); // some value
```

Na minha concepção o uso de colchetes é possível somente em listas para passarmos um índice direto ou ter uma variável de incrementação para percorrer todos os objetos.

Como que isso é possível? Quando eu acesso **['title']** ele percorre todas as *keys* (`Object.keys`) de objeto até encontrar a chave pedida ou vai direto ao "índice"?

Comment: Eu acho que isto já foi perguntado aqui antes, preciso ver se acho a duplicata.

Comment: O uso dos colchetes é questão de sintaxe. Não tem essa de "só é possível para tal coisa". Cada linguagem faz de um jeito. Python, por exemplo, usa isso para listas, tuplas, dicionários e strings.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Já respondi quase toda dúvida aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40682/101).

Existe uma [pergunta que trata o geral do assunto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/39993/101) (sugiro ler para obter todos os detalhes). Em resumo, os objetos do JS na verdade são *arrays* (associativos). Então cada membro do objeto no fundo é uma chave do *array*. Quando acessa `obj.title`, no fundo está acessando `obj["title"]`. É essencialmente açúcar sintático.

Isso é usado por várias [linguagens dinâmicas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21508/101).

A implementação exata disso depende do *engine* que está sendo usado, mas posso garantir que todos usam algum mecanismo de [tabela *hash*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tabela_de_dispers%C3%A3o) para que a busca pelas chaves ocorram em [complexidade O(1)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/56868/101) - tempo constante. Então pode-se dizer que ele vai direto ao "índice", ainda que tenha um passo anterior.

```js
var meuObjeto = {
    a: 1,
    "b": 2
};
for (var chave in meuObjeto) console.log("key " + chave + "; value " + meuObjeto[chave]);
console.log("tipo: " + typeof(meuObjeto));
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Object/LikeArray.js).

Comment: Muito bom os links, principalmente o primeiro. É, minha dúvida era realmente em como ele fazia acesso ao atributo, que como você disse, é com tabela hash. Javascript é uma linguagem bem confusa, a sorte é que tem ótimos artigos no stack over flow para nos salvar, aliais, tem algum lugar onde consigo ter acesso a todos de uma determinada linguagem ?

Comment: A linguagem é confuso e ao mesmo tempo bem interessante. Acessem as *tags* http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags. Exemplo: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript?sort=votes&pageSize=50 organize como quiser, na busca dá para fazer filtros diversos.

Answer (score 8):

TL;DR: **Sim**, de maneira genérica - com alguns poréns.

Resposta longa: Todos os tipos prototípicos do javascript (`Boolean`, `Number`, `String`, `Function`, `Array`, `Date` e `RegExp`) são implementações que expandem o comportamento de `Object`.

No caso de `Array`, cujo foco é indexação numérica de dados, métodos como `push()` e propriedades como `length` são implementados.

Entretanto você ainda pode utilizar as funções prototípicas de Object, como propriedades indexadas:

```
var myArray = Array();

myArray['A'] = "Athens";
myArray['B'] = "Berlin";

console(myArray.length); // Resultado será zero
```

O valor de `length` no exemplo acima é zero porque o valor *não foi adicionado utilizando a implementação presente no protótipo array* - ao invés disso, ele foi *adicionado ao objeto*.

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/874205/what-is-the-difference-between-an-array-and-an-object

Answer (score 4):

Não, mas possuem algumas semelhanças. Apesar de você poder acessar as propriedades da mesma forma, os métodos que cada um possui são diferentes.

Exemplo:

```
a = {};
b = [];
console.log(a.forEach); //undefined
console.log(b.forEach); //function forEach(){ ... }
```