# Por que o comportamento da variável indefinida é diferente da propriedade indefinida?

Tags: javascript, variáveis, propriedade

Venho notado isso há muito tempo em Javascript.

Se eu escrevo um determinado código onde a variável não está definida em qualquer escopo, uma exceção é lançada:

```
console.log(preco)
```

Resultado:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: preco is not defined

Mas se eu tentar acessar uma propriedade não definida, nenhum erro é lançado, mas apenas `undefined` é retornado:

```
  var obj = {};

  console.log(obj.id); // undefined
  console.log(window.preco); // undefined
```

Por que o JavaScript se comporta dessa forma?

Answer (score 3):

Por causa da natureza das duas.

A variável é algo mais concreto na linguagem, ela deve existir no código, tem como verificar e saber se existe ou não.

A propriedade de um objeto parece uma variável, mas não é, [é só uma chave em um *array* associativo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40682/101). Não tem como o interpretador do JS ter certeza se existe ou não, pode existir uma hora, não existir em outra. Os objetos em JS são abertos para modificação dinâmica em sua estrutura a qualquer tempo.

```
obj.id
```

na verdade é

```
obj["id"]
```

Claro que poderia existir uma forma que detecte o problema e gerar um erro, mas resolverem ser consistentes com o [mecanismo da tabela usada no *array* associativo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/122341/101) que justamente é considerar que o elemento que não existe é apenas indefinido e não gerar um erro. O jeito de saber se uma chave existe é justamente comparar com `undefined`.

Então se acessar o elemento na tabela, não ocorre erro algum, mesmo que ele não exista, é só uma chave inexistente naquele momento. Linguagens de tipagem dinâmica tem essa vantagem de ser flexível e a desvantagem de ser menos robusta e exigir que o programador se preocupe em fazer certo, testando antes de usar, seja por testes de unidade, ou por teste no código mesmo, se ele pode se virar se der um erro.

```js
var obj = {
    a : 1
};
console.log(obj.a);
console.log(obj.b);
if (obj.b == undefined) console.log("propriedade não existe");
obj.b = 2;
console.log(obj.b);
for (var chave in obj) console.log(chave + " = " + obj[chave]);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Typing/Undefined.js).

Comment: Depois do almoço, eu voto :p

Answer (score 1):

Uma variável não declarada não está listada no [VariableEnvironment](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.3).

No seu exemplo:

```
console.log(preco)
```

Isso significa que o identificador `preco` não é resolvido para nenhum objeto armazenado no `VariableEnvironment`; uma exceção indicando a não-definição é gerada ( `$ident is not defined`).

Uma variável declarada porém não inicializada recebe o valor padrão `undefined`, que é ao mesmo tempo uma propriedade do objeto `global` e um dos [tipos primitivos do javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined). No seu exemplo:

```
var obj = {};
console.log(obj.id);
```

A propriedade `id` (que nada mais é do que uma chave que aponta para um membro da coleção de propriedades do objeto `obj`) não aponta para nenhum objeto.

Entretanto, a coleção procurada não é `VariableEnvironment`, mas sim apenas a coleção de propriedades: O valor retornado é o global `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

Não sei exatamente o motivo de funcionar assim, mas o que eu notei é que a excepção de uma variável indefinida nos ajuda à descobrir se ela existe ou não, seja global ou local.

```
try {
    aa
} catch(e) {
    // não existe
}
```

Já para propriedades de objetos isso dificulta a detecção da presença de uma propriedade em navegadores antigos (tipo MsIE6), mas graças ao operador `in` isso torna possível, com uma exceção.

De qualquer forma, não faria sentido uma propriedade inexistente lançar uma excepção, talvez queriam evitar problemas com expressões:

```
!!b
```

Só de uma excepção ser lançada, a execução desse bloco para, há não ser que haja um `try/catch/finally` para proteger a excepção.

Atualmente, para descobrirmos se a propriedade de um objeto existe precisamos de um método nativo ou operador, a propriedade pode ser `undefined`, qualquer tipo de valor. `Object#hasOwnProperty` resolve isso, o operador `in` fará o mesmo, só que profundamente, vai verificar se a propriedade específica existe nas propriedades dos construtores, também.

Aviso¹: o *nome* de todas as propriedades de um objeto/função são *convertidos* para string;
Aviso²: ambos *funções* e *objetos* podem *guardar* propriedades em sí mesmo;
Aviso³: todos valores numéricos, strings, objetos, funções e booleans podem ser indexados `.` ou `[...]`, menos `null` e `undefined`–

```
var a = {
    b: undefined
}

// Diz que a.b não existe
typeof a.b !== 'undefined'

// Diz que a.b existe
a in 'b'

// Diz que a.b existe
a.hasOwnProperty('b')
```

E essa é a maneira mais usada para checar se uma propriedade existe:

```
// Se a.b for um valor verdadeiro,
// diz sim
!!a.b
```