# Ajuda - result.forEach is not a function

Tags: angular

Como eu faço um `forEach` no retorno de um subscribe?

```
this.service.obterTodos()
.subscribe(result => {
    result.forEach(element => {
       this.usuComponent.push(element);
    });
});
```

Service:

```
obterTodos(): Observable<Usuario[]> {
    return this.httpClient.get<Usuario[]>("URL");
}
```

Erro:

```
ERROR TypeError: result.forEach is not a function
```

<sup>[Imagem do error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zgpqN.png)</sup>

Result:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Que informações adicionais eu preciso postar para que você me ajude?

Comment: 1) Não poste código como imagem; você já é usuário ativo no site e sabe que o mesmo tem suporte a código fonte. 2) Certifique-se que `result` é o valor que você esperava que fosse. É um *array*?

Comment: Você tem razão, perdão por postar como imagem... Coloquei o meu result no post

Comment: tenta result.result.foreach

Comment: @EduardoVargas, não permite, fica sublinhado em vermelho

Comment: Leo, por que no print do result você ofuscou uma parte? São dados sensíveis?

Comment: Veja também o resultado de `console.log(typeof result)`

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss é o nome verdadeiro do meu objeto

Comment: Por que ofuscar o nome do objeto? E o resultado do `typeof`?

Comment: Pra nao haver confusão, coloquei no exemplo usuario, ai iam questionar o q é aquele outro nome ali, vc nao esta passando errado, so pra evitar esse tipo de comentario... Resultado do typeof é object

Comment: Aí está então. Seu `result` é um objeto, não um *array*. Deveria ser um *array*? Você tem controle sobre o recurso que foi requisitado no servidor? Ele retorna JSON?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94358/discussion-between-leohenrique-and-anderson-carlos-woss).

Comment: Possivelmente relacionada: [O que é um Array-Like?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/39996/3774)

Answer (score 0):

Creio que `result` é um array de HTML elementos, certo? Se sim, `result` é um "[tipo de Array](http://2ality.com/2013/05/quirk-array-like-objects.html)" (Array like) e não um Array em si. Tente assim:

```
Array.from(result).forEach(element => {
    this.usuComponent.push(element);
});
```

ou

```
[...result].forEach(element => {
    this.usuComponent.push(element);
});
```

Comment: Para esse, Array.from(result) deu undefined, para esse, [...result] deu result.slice .is not a function

Answer (score -2):

Tenta assim:

```
this.service.obterTodos()
.subscribe((response:any)=> {
    response.result.forEach(element => {
       this.usuComponent.push(element);
    });
});
```

Comment: Não é a mesma coisa que sugeriu nos [comentários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/388103/ajuda-result-foreach-is-not-a-function#comment765753_388103)?

Comment: tem um any na response

Comment: Então seria interessante explicar porquê isso faz diferença

Comment: se ele der o joinha que deu certo eu edito a resposta explicando.

Comment: @EduardoVargas TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined (undefined é o result)

Comment: parece que nem sua resposta é um array. Nem tem uma propriedade que seja.

Comment: mas o que seria entao? Porque ali no print, tem varios objetos dentro