# Os objetos nativos do JS são arrays associativos?

Tags: javascript, array, objetos, array-associativo

E os *arrays* associativos são como objetos nativos do JS?

E as strings literais/dado primitivo? O que entendo é que elas são instâncias do objeto *string*, porém com a diferença de serem *arrays* indexados, correto?

Estou com dificuldades de entender os conceitos de *array* x objeto. Parece que isso é mais subjetivo do que concreto.

Comment: Eu não gosto muito de JS então talvez eu esteja falando bobagem mas nem os próprios Arrays existem no JS. Existem Objetos que representam coleções de dados e possuem propriedades e métodos prototipados. O que comumente conhecemos como array associativo, seriam os *hash maps*, que também nada mais são do que objetos.

Comment: Me da alguma fonte em portugues que explique sobre prototipação, por favor? ^^

Comment: @ropbla9 Serve essa? ["Como funcionam protótipos em JavaScript?"](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15239/215) De fato, não parece haver diferença prática entre um objeto e um array, exceto que este possui `Array` como protótipo. Acho que se você criar um objeto normal com o protótipo `Array` (ou `Array.prototype`, não sei) e uma propriedade `length` ele se comportaria exatamente como um array. Vou fazer um teste...

Comment: P.S. Não, de fato algumas operações aplicadas num array (tipo acrescentar novos elementos na forma `arr[indice] = elemento;`) atualizam seu índice, enquanto num objeto qualquer isso não ocorre, independentemente do seu protótipo. São tipos diferentes mesmo, propriamente falando.

Comment: Não são tipos diferentes (nos termos da especificação). Na verdade arrays são um subtipo peculiar de objeto, @mgibsonbr. Ver http://perfectionkills.com/how-ecmascript-5-still-does-not-allow-to-subclass-an-array/

Comment: @bfavaretto Se é um subtipo é um tipo diferente, não? :P Dei uma passada de olho no link que você indicou, e é justamente por conta de alguns desses "fenômenos" observados [quando se tenta criar uma subclasse de array] que eu fiz essa afirmação. Mas confesso que eu próprio não tenho 100% de certeza, formalmente falando.

Comment: @mgibsonbr É que formalmente são definidos só 6 tipos: String, Number, Boolean (os primitivos), Null, Undefined e Object. Arrays e funções são tratados como casos especiais.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## TL;DR

Pode-se entender que são mas na realidade não é bem assim. Foi criado para dar esta aparência embora a implementação não seja bem essa. Strings também. Depende se você está olhando a implementação ou o conceito formal.

## Conceitos

Algo pode ser subjetivo e concreto, esses conceitos não são antagônicos. Neste caso o funcionamento é objetivo e concreto. O conceito pode ser um pouco mais abstrato, apesar de objetivo. Mas todo conceito é uma abstração.

Talvez você queira dizer que entender isto não seja importante. Para fazer o básico realmente não importa mas quando você vai sendo criativo, vai querendo ir além do arroz com feijão, entender isto é fundamental. Só a total especialização permite explorar uma linguagem que possui poucas abstrações mas grandes possibilidades de criar suas próprias, que o diga os milhares de *frameworks* criados.

Não sou um profundo estudioso da linguagem e é provável que surjam respostas melhores que a minha.

## Detalhando

Você está certo, os objetos em JS são *arrays* associativos ou *hashes* ou dicionários ou *maps* como também podem ser chamados (embora tecnicamente não podemos classificar assim no caso do JavaScript que só permite chaves do tipo `String`). Isto simplificou a criação da linguagem. Pelo menos a implementação é feita com eles.

Então sim, esses *arrays* são entendidos pela linguagem nativamente. Mas eles são entendidos como objetos e não como *arrays*. Eles são um pouco mais do que *[syntax sugar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar)* para *arrays*. Há um entendimento da linguagem em como os objetos funcionam.  A **sintaxe** pode ser parcialmente intercambiada dando poder e flexibilidade em vários aspectos. Note que formalmente JS só possui "nativamente" o tipo `Object`. Ele funciona como um *array* associativo mas não é considerado um, formalmente falando.

O que impede um tipo ter uma implementação mais concreta mas ser reconhecido de forma mais abstrata? Isto é a base da programação moderna (para o bem ou para o mal).

## String

Você tem que pensar no tipo [String](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) de duas formas. Existe um tipo abstrato que encapsula uma *string* (lembrando que em JS cada variável pode ser de qualquer tipo e inclusive pode mudar o tipo mas o dado, o valor em si não muda de tipo nunca, se achar que mudou o tipo, mudou o dado). Concretamente este objeto tem suas propriedades em chaves associadas a um *array*. Uma destas propriedade é o texto da *string* propriamente dito (o que não deixa de ser uma outra abstração já que um texto nada mais é que um *array* de caracteres). A linguagem tem alguns entendimentos extras com este objeto. Ele não é um objeto qualquer criado pelo usuário, é algo que tem relevância maior para a linguagem. Há um tratamento especial para este tipo.

String pode ser usada de forma mais convencional como objeto:

```
var x = "texto"; //ajudado pela linguagem como string
var y = new String("texto"); //ajudado pela linguagem como objeto
```

Mas note que há diferenças. A primeira forma é otimizada. A segunda funciona mais como um objeto normal. A recomendação é não usar a segunda forma.

Se é sobre isto que você acha que alguma coisa pode ser considerado nativo, então acho que ficou mais claro, a linguagem tem entendimento maior sobre alguns tipos de dados definidos nela e consegue dar um tratamento especial. Mas todos os tipos tendem a serem usados como se fossem objetos normais. Muito provavelmente a forma como as propriedades e métodos dos tipos primitivos são acessados seja diferente de um objeto "normal" mas na aparência, na abstração, é quase a mesma coisa.

## Implementação

Evidentemente a forma exata como é implementado é um [detalhe de implementação](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/154144/how-to-define-implementation-details). Cada interpretador/compilador pode fazer do jeito que achar melhor desde que atenda todos os requisitos da linguagem que todo usuário dela espera. Para isto existe uma [especificação da linguagem](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm).

Note que não estou dizendo que todos os objetos em JavaScript são implementados exatamente como se fossem *arrays* associativos da linguagem, até porque não existem *arrays* associativos na especificação da linguagem. A sintaxe realmente permite acessar dados de um objeto como se fossem *arrays* de propriedades mas há uma diferença de implementação interna.

Quando você cria um [Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) você não pode fazer um `push()` ou um `sort()` ou acessar `.length` da estrutura do objeto (claro que o seu tipo pode ter uma das propriedades com este nome) que é possível fazer em um [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) (um tipo que não faz parte da linguagem e sim da biblioteca). Eles são tipos diferentes que funcionam de forma semelhante. Podemos dizer que um objeto é um *array-like* mas não o tipo `Array` mesmo.

O mesmo vale para `String`, parece mas ela não é apenas um `Array` com propriedades e uma dessas propriedades é um outro `Array` de caracteres (JS nem tem o conceito de caractere único como em outras linguagens, um caractere sozinho não deixa de ser uma *string*).

Mas você pode varrer (com `for in`)  todos os elementos de um objeto **como se fosse** um `Array`. Você pode fazer o mesmo com um texto, caractere a caractere. Mas isto não os torna um `Array` normal da linguagem, ele ainda é um `Object`.

Não confundir um objeto em termos gerais com um `Array`. Claro que o tipo `Array` não deixa de ser um objeto, ele vem do mesmo protótipo de `Object` mas o contrário não é verdadeiro. Um `Object` qualquer não é construído com um `Array`, até porque você teria um problema do ovo e da galinha. O mesmo vale para `String`. Como os objetos precisam de *strings* para suas chaves o tipo `String` não poderia depender do `Object` para existir.

```js
var meuObjeto = { a: 1, "b": 2 };
for (var chave in meuObjeto) console.log("key " + chave + "; value " + meuObjeto[chave]);
console.log("tipo: " + typeof(meuObjeto));
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Object/ListMembers.js).

## Conclusão

Existe aí uma confusão entre a implementação concreta que sim, é baseada em *array* associativo e o conceito formal que trata esses *arrays* como objetos e só.

Mas já vi outras definições sobre o assunto. Eu imagino que isto tem a ver com o fato que existem implementações diferentes. Por isto, em geral (mas não em todos os casos), **não é importante entender a implementação e sim a abstração exposta no padrão da linguagem**. O que você precisa entender é que as propriedades de um objeto podem ser acessadas da mesma forma como é feito em um *array* associativo e isto traz vantagens, torna a linguagem mais dinâmica.

Veja a [lista de objetos *built-in* na MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects). Não quer dizer que todos eles fazem parte da linguagem.

Comment: não poderia existir resposta melhor que a tua. Entendi uma porcentagem mais do que satisfatória e isso salvou muito do meu tempo. Se tivesse como eu marcaria certo 1000x, no entanto eu só posso agradecer de coração, haha.

Comment: @ropbla9 pode sim, eu acho até que vai aparecer. De qualquer forma leia tudo o que puder sobre o assunto. Já tem ótimas informações na resposta do mgibsonbr. Ainda vou melhorar a minha. Tem algumas coisas que não estão claras e estou pesquisando (p/ o meu benefício as melhores perguntas são as que me fazem pesquisar) para complementar.

Answer (score 7):

Eu não sei o que você entende por "array associativo", mas o fato é que em JavaScript todo tipo "objeto" pode receber propriedades cuja chave é textual. Arrays são objetos, mas strings nem sempre (ver [resposta do Maniero](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/40686/215) para mais detalhes).

```js
var tipos = [0, 0.0, true, "teste", new String("teste"), [], {}, /regex/, function() { }];
tipos.forEach(function(dado) {
  dado.foo = "bar";
  $("<tr></tr>")
      .append("<td>" + dado + "</td>")
      .append("<td>" + typeof dado + "</td>")
      .append("<td>" + (dado.foo == "bar") + "</td>")
      .appendTo($("table tbody"));
});
// null e undefined lançariam uma exceção no teste acima
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr><th>Dado</th><th>typeof</th><th>Propriedades arbitrárias?</th></tr>
</table>
```

A propósito, **toda** chave é textual, somente. Se você faz `array[0] = 10` isso é o mesmo que fazer `array["0"] = 10`, para todos os efeitos. Da mesma forma, não dá pra usar um objeto complexo como chave (diferentemente de um dicionário ou *map* mais geral, como temos em outras linguagens) pois ele será convertido em string antes de ser inserido:

```js
function log(texto) {
  $("<p>" + texto + "</p>").appendTo($("#saida"));
}

var arr = [];
log(arr.length); // 0
arr[0] = 10;
log(arr.length); // 1
arr["1"] = 20;
log(arr.length); // 2
arr.push(30);
log(arr.length); // 3
log(JSON.stringify(arr)); // [10, 20, 30]

var obj = {};
obj.foo = 10;
obj["bar"] = 20;
obj[{ um:"objeto" }] = 30;
obj[{ outro:"objeto" }] = 40;
log(JSON.stringify(obj)); // { "foo":10, "bar": 20, "[object Object]":40 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="saida"></div>
```

Num futuro próximo, haverá suporte para um [`Map`](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-map-objects) propriamente dito (i.e. que utiliza qualquer objeto como chave), mas objetos comuns somente aceitam strings, ou convertem o que quer que for passado para o subscrito em uma string antes de utilizar.

Quanto a acessar strings como arrays, não sei ao certo como está especificado, mas na prática acessar um índice de uma string te retorna uma **substring** com um único caractere:

```
var str = "abc";
var ch = str[1];
typeof ch; // string
ch == "b"; // true
```

Usar `str.charAt(indice)` produz o mesmo resultado.

Se você quer os "caracteres" propriamente ditos, uma maneira é obter os *code units* (16 bits) usando o método [`str.charCodeAt(indice)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt), que te retorna o caractere como um número inteiro (no EcmaScript 6 haverá também o `str.codePointAt(indice)`, esse retornando qualquer *code point* inclusive nos [SMPs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_%28Unicode%29#Supplementary_Multilingual_Plane)). O processo inverso pode ser feito via [`String.fromCharCode(inteiro, ...)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode) (ou `String.fromCodePoint(...)`).