# O que é DOM, Render Tree e Node?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

Sou iniciante no JS e procuro entender a teoria, só que todos os artigos que encontro sobre DOM são demasiadamente "científicos".

Não haveria uma forma mais simples de explicar isso para um "leigo"?

Comment: Usualmente o HTML é lido pelo navegador e organizado em um DOM internamente. Esse DOM é composto por vários nodes, uns dentro dos outros, que são gerados pelas tags originais e seus conteúdos. O Render-tree é a árvore composta pelo _engine_ do browser, compondo o DOM com o CSS para definir como as coisas serão desenhadas na tela, em que posição, ordem e acabamento visual.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

## DOM

Domain Object Model.

Em palavras bem simples o DOM é um grande objeto hierárquico com diversos elementos formando uma árvore. Nele você encontra todos os elementos existentes no modelo que ele se refere. No caso dos *browsers* você encontra os elementos existentes no próprio *browser* e na página que está acessando. Mas lembre-se que DOM não é um conceito exclusivo de *browsers*.

## Node

O *node* ou nó é justamente esse elemento que estou falando, é um nó no modelo. É um elo desses dados todos interligados. Uma *tag* é um nó, mas dentro desse nó existem outros nós, existem os *atributos* só para citar um exemplo. Dentro dos atributos existem outros nós. E assim vai. Um nó só pode ser terminador quando ele tiver uma informação muito simples. Enquanto precisar de uma estrutura, uma coleção de dados para guardar o nó o DOM vai depender de outros nós.

## Detalhando

Então você vai tendo um objeto de dentro do outro formando essa hierarquia. O DOM se assemelha muito ao código HTML que você escreve. Mas ele pode conter quaisquer coisas que pertençam ao domínio que ele trata. No caso do DOM do HTML ele terá todas informações sobre as *tags* usadas. E algumas das propriedades dos elementos contidos em uma página são manipulados pelo próprio HTML, especialmente se estiver usando HTML5. Outros serão manipulados pelo CSS e ainda existem outros que serão manipulados pelo JavaScript. Nada impede que um elemento possa ser manipulado por todas essas tecnologias. O que você manipula é o DOM. O DOM serve primariamente ao computador e não ao ser humano. O HTML serve ao humano, ele é mais visual, tem coisas supérfluas para o computador.

Normalmente ele é montando na memória de uma forma mais simples do que você vê no seu código, afinal o seu código precisa da informação visual para exibição. O DOM só precisa da informação mínima para funcionar o que ele define.

O DOM tem uma relação direta com o seu HTML mas não necessariamente é uma relação um para um. Deficiências no HTML pode produzir um DOM um pouco diferente.

Pegando carona na [sua outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40682/101). Pense nele como um enorme *array* associativo onde alguns elementos desse *array* possuem outros *arrays* (que são outros nós) e vai acumulando tudo o que é necessário para sua página (seu domínio). Quando um desses elementos não é um *array* ele é um nó terminador, ou seja, é um nó que possui alguma informação final. No DOM do JavaScript essa informação pode ser até mesmo um código. No DOM do HTML você vai encontrar propriedades, eventos e até métodos.

Ele também é usado em objetos [SVG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics).

O JavaScript possui métodos para manipular todo o DOM. Por isto é a forma mais flexível para obter resultados diferenciados. Claro que seu uso tem outras desvantagens que não cabem nesta resposta. Esta manipulação é feito com a chamada [API](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/17552/101). Esta API é esse conjunto de métodos que manipulam o DOM que eu me referi antes.

Exemplo de manipulação do DOM: imagine o HTML assim:

```
<div id="container">texto atual</div>

<script>
  var container = document.getElementById("container");
  container.innerHTML = "mudei o texto";
</script>
```

Quando executar este *script* o seu HTML não mudará mas o seu DOM mudará e ficará de uma forma que é o mesmo que se tivesse escrito:

```
<div id="container">mudei o texto</div>
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/DOM/Dom.html).

Mas vou repetir, o HTML não muda! O HTML é apenas uma instrução, não é o dado concreto. É a instrução inicial que cria o DOM. A instrução não muda. O dado real muda. Lembre-se que HTML é um código e não um dado (como todo código pode ter dados dentro dele). Códigos são instruções. Apesar de [HTML não ser uma linguagem de programação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/35548/101) é uma linguagem que instrui o computador fazer algo.

O [artigo da Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) é científico demais? (Não acho ele muito bom, mas parece que dá para entender, pelo menos agora que já tem informações novas).

Sabe inglês? (Programador precisa saber). Veja [esse artigo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction).

Está com paciência? Veja [como os *browsers* funcionam](https://taligarsiel.com/Projects/howbrowserswork1.htm).

## Render Tree

Isto é uma árvore que o *browser* guarda internamente para representar os elementos visuais. Ela é diferente da árvore de *tags* do HTML e do DOM em si. Ela é usada para desenhar ou pintar (o termo mais usado em renderização) os elementos na tela. Isto é necessário, por exemplo, para saber a ordem que cada elemento deve ser desenhado para produzir o resultado final desejado (um dos motivos que algumas [renderizações são muito diferentes de *browser* para *browser*](https://codepen.io/MartijnCuppens/pen/MXojmw). Então os elementos vão sendo pintados seguindo esta árvore. É neste momento que as posições dos elementos serão calculados já que muitos deles estarão em posições relativas à posição de seus pais.

[image: Diferenças de renderizações]

## Adição final

O CSS possui um "DOM" próprio, ele é chamado de [CSSOM](https://dev.w3.org/csswg/cssom/).

[image: Diagramas dos DOM, CSSOM e render tree]

Algumas mudaram em navegadores mais modernos.

Comment: 1) Um nó seria um uma tag ou uma propriedade dela? 2)E quando vc manipula uma tag do DOM com JS tipo document.getE... por que isso é um API? 3) N entendi inteiramente a diferença de DOM e HTML.

Comment: @robpla9 entra um HTML no browser. O browser vai lendo e "catando" as TAGS e armazenando na memória como "nós" (nodes), com seu conteúdo, tipo e atributos. Não tem sentido o HTML ficar sendo processado como texto. Assim como se vc pegar um JSON (que é um mero texto), vai converter ele num objeto ou array pra trabalhar, o browser faz o mesmo com seu HTML.

Comment: @ropbla9 eu editei para tentar colocar essas dúvidas, veja se ajudou. Leia a outra resposta, ela mostra uma outra perspectiva que ajuda entender.

Comment: @maniero Seria correto dizer: o browser implementa um loop que lê uma determinada posição de memoria, nessa posição de memoria esta localizado o conteúdo da pagina em questão (o DOM). Então quando faço uma alteração na minha tela usando javascript estou na verdade alterando uma valor na memoria, consequentemente quando o browser fazer um refresh minha alteração será visível ?

Comment: @FilipeCanatto Como cada *browser* faz é problema dele. Obviamente que qualquer alteração de estado em qualquer linguagem está alterando um valor na memória, não importa o que. De forma geral acredito que não seja assim já que seria ineficiente. Provavelmente trabalha com eventos, onde a alteração já dispara as ações necessárias.

Answer (score 28):

### HTML

```html
<div>
    <p>Um parágrafo em cima.</p>
    <p>Outro <span>embaixo</span>.</p>
    <p>E mais um</p>
</div>
```

### DOM

```
div
  -- p
  -- p
    -- span 
  -- p
```

O DOM representa o HTML em uma árvore de elementos. Ele é um modelo do seu documento HTML, por isso o nome *Document Object Model*. Cada elemento é um *nó* (*Node*) da árvore. O HTML é processado uma vez, mas a árvore do DOM pode ser alterada (por JavaScript ou CSS) depois que a página já carregou.

Na realidade é um pouco mais complexo que no esquema acima. Os textos e atributos do HTML também são nós da árvore. Comentários como `<!-- -->` também. Mas minha intenção ali é somente ilustrar o conceito.

<sub>*Render tree* não sei ao certo, em que contexto você ouviu/leu isso? Pode ser a própria árvore do DOM, em seu estado atual, ou uma outra árvore que o browser usa para definir a ordem com que desenhará os elementos na tela.</sub>