# Como estes sites carregam seu HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, json

Acabei observando códigos-fonte de sites como Gmail.com e Secret.ly e observei que o HTML está embutido no JavaScript, que tecnologia é essa que eles usam?

Fica desta forma:

```
<script>var codes = {"AutoControlHeader":true,"CanSubscribe":false,"Collection":{"Description":"Popu‌​lar secrets from across the world that our community has loved.","ItemCount":272,"Slug":"popular","Title":"Popular"},"CountryCodes":[{"Co‌​de":"al","PhonePrefix":"+355","Name":"Albania"},{"Code":"dz","PhonePrefi
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Interface construída dinamicamente

O que você está vendo são sites cujas interfaces são total ou parcialmente construídas via JavaScript, ou seja, código que executa no seu navegador.

Geralmente você recebe um HTML bem básico quando acessa a página, mais um conjunto de dados, mais alguns scripts.

Posteriormente, mais dados podem ser carregados ao longo do tempo em requisições assíncronas usando Ajax.

## Para que serve

Este tipo de técnica foge um pouco dos padrões da web, sendo geralmente é adotado para melhorar incrementar a experiência do usuário, não fazendo-o esperar pelo carregamento de página após página.

Isso dá a sensação de usar um programa convencional ao invés de um site da web.

## Problemas

Por outro lado, desenvolver aplicações web desse tipo é mais trabalhoso e mais propenso a erros.

## Exemplos

[*Single page applications*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application) (aplicações de uma única página), pela sua própria natureza, geralmente adotam esse tipo de estratégia.

É o caso, por exemplo, do Gmail. Ele carrega todo o código e estruturas necessárias logo que você o acessa. Depois, você pode realizar uma séria de tarefas sem transferência de dados do servidor.

Nos aplicativos do Google em geral, há inclusive suporte parcial para trabalhar offline.

## Como isso é feito na prática

Em geral há duas estratégias para geração dinâmica de elementos:

### Criação de elementos programaticamente

Cão criadas instâncias de objetos que representam as tags HTML e então elas são adicionadas em algum lugar da página.

Isso é feito com a função [`createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createElement) do JavaScript. Exemplo:

```js
//cria tag <p>
var minhaDiv = document.createElement("p"); 

//adiciona um texto
var conteudo = document.createTextNode("Olá!"); 
minhaDiv.appendChild(conteudo);

//adiciona tag na página
document.body.appendChild(minhaDiv);
```

### Criação com base num template HTML

Pode-se também injetar um trecho de código HTML em algum lugar da página.

Isso pode ser feito usando-se o atributo [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.innerHTML) de algum elemento existente na página. Exemplo:

```js
//substitui todo o conteúdo da página por "Olá"
document.body.innerHTML = "Olá";
```

Há alguma diferença de desempenho entre as duas formas, mas no fim o resultado é o mesmo.

Comment: Muito Obrigado, voce captou minha pergunta e respondeu o que eu queria. Vou trabalhar com SPA pois gosto da tecnica..

Answer (score 8):

Isso não é HTML, isto é JavaScript. Esta é a notação de objetos. É apenas uma estrutura de dados com informações relevantes que poderão ser processadas em determinado momento. Estes dados apresentados é uma notação serializada (textualizada) de um objeto JavaScript com propriedades (antes do `:`) e valores (depois dele). Cada chave é um objeto. Como é possível perceber alguns valores são outros objetos formando uma árvore de dados. Por acaso isto está dentro do código JavaScript que está dentro do HTML.

Essencialmente é o mesmo formato do [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) que foi criado com sintaxe semelhante ao encontrada no JavaScript para descrever objetos. Você pode ter esta notação dentro do seu código mas o mais comum é transportar estes dados em chamadas ao servidor requisitando apenas dados. Uma técnica comum para fazer isto sem carregar a página novamente é o [AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)). Veja mais sobre as diferenças entre esses objetos e JSON [nessa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/41140/101). A pergunta não é muito boa porque o AP não conhece o assunto mas as respostas mostram direitinho.

Com estes dados pode sim montar outras partes de HTML manipulando o [DOM](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40852/101). O jQuery tornou esta manipulação mais fácil. E hoje tem uma profusão de *frameworks* fazendo o mesmo. parece que nenhum é bom o suficiente por isto sempre surge um novo.

Técnicas como esta são muito usadas em páginas que devem servir como aplicativos. Mas cuidado para não aplicá-la em lugares errados. Isto é péssimo para *sites* comuns:

- Você fica muito dependente do JavaScript e se não souber o que está fazendo impedirá muitas pessoas de verem seu *site* corretamente ou por completo.
- Esconde a informação dos buscadores. E cria uma entrada única onde poderia haver várias especializadas (dá para resolver mas não é simples).
- Se não souber o que está fazendo vai criar problemas de segurança mais facilmente. E acredite, a maioria das pessoas que fazem isto, criam problemas de segurança.
- Dá muito mais trabalho do que parece manter um estado consistente.

O Gmail, por exemplo, até hoje tem problemas. Já foi pior. Eles possuem vários dos melhores engenheiros do planeta e a coisa tá capenga ainda.

Eu adoro SPA, se eu fosse WebDev eu preferiria usar esta técnica mas sei que não é o adequado em muitos cenários.

Se realmente quiser se aprofundar nisto, faça com dedicação. Não pare nos *links* que achou nesta página.

[Sobre SPA](http://singlepageappbook.com/single-page.html). [Mais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/354845/101).

Comment: Consegui entender perfeitamente, muito obrigado a voce que explicou que eles colocaram os dados no js pra depois carregar com auxilio de SPA como o amigo de cima disse.

Comment: Pena que SPA, utiliza recursos do navegador, e se mal aplicados, fará o mesmo usar mais memória ram, e fazer o sistema ficar mais lento =\

Comment: @Rod Existem outros problemas, além deste. O pessoal está abusando no seu uso.

Comment: @bigown sim, é um deles...são vários, há pontos positivos e negativos, eu acredito que SPA não é uma boa para aplicações corporativas