# JSON é igual a um array Associativo?

Tags: javascript, array, json

Os dois são a mesma coisa? Ou JSON é uma biblioteca ou tecnica mais complexa?

Comment: [JSON](http://json.org) é um formato de dados (como o XML, YAML, etc). Ele pode ser usado para serializar um array associativo, se assemelhando a um literal de objetos em JavaScript: `{ "chave":"valor", "outraChave":42, "outra":[1,2,3] }`. Mas JSON é **texto**, e pode ser produzido/consumido por qualquer linguagem, não somente JavaScript.

Comment: @mgibsonbr aah, é texto. Entendi. É uma espécie de XML com cara de linguagem de programação.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JSON é um standard de como escrever/formatar conteudo numa `string`.
JSON quer dizer JavaScript Object Notation mas na verdade esse formato criado pelo Douglas Crockford foi adaptado por diversas linguagens e é hoje o formato standard para enviar conteudo entre aplicações e plataformas.

Assim à semelhança do YAML  e do XML o JSON é texto puro. As regras de formatação são simples e a autoridade para o verificar é o http://jsonlint.com/. Basicamente:

- Os dados escrevem-se em pares chave/valor
- Os dados são separados por vigulas
- Para referir objetos usa-se `{`
- Para referir arrays usa-se `[`
- As aspas usadas são as aspas duplas `"`

Portanto o JSON é texto e Arrays são específicas da linguagem e são representações dinamicas de dados com propriedades como `length`, index e outras dependendo da linguagem.

#### Exemplos:

Em JavaScript para declarar uma array faz-se

```
var arr = ['foo', 'bar'];
```

A mesma array em JSON seria uma string:

```
var arrayJSON = '{ "arr": ["foo", "bar"]}';
```

Repare que seguindo a sintaxe do JSON temos sempre que dar uma chave para cada valor. E para usar em JavaScript teria de converter com o [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

```
var arr = JSON.parse(arrayJSON).arr;
```

Para usar a mesma array no formato JSON em PHP teria de fazer:

```
$arr = json_decode('{ "arr": ["foo", "bar"]}', true);
```

Comment: como posso entrar no chat contigo?

Answer (score 2):

Não tem nada a ver. JSON é uma coisa e um array associativo é outra coisa.

JSON significa Javascript Object Notation, e é uma espécie de "Array serializado", ou seja, você pode gerar ele e transportar  de lugar para lugar em forma de string, o que torna muito mais fácil a movimentação de dados com este tipo de formato. JSON é um subset do javascript e derivados. ([Referência](http://www.json.org/))

Um array associativo, dependendo da linguagem, é uma espécie de dicionário, ele tem chaves que podem ser strings e associar elas a valores, por exemplo:

```
[URL] => Array ( [Chave] => [Valor] );
```

A diferença está na manipulação de ambos, enquanto JSON pode ser "convertido" em uma string comum, o array é um objeto que precisará ser serializado para que seja feito o transporte de dados, por isso é mais fácil usar JSON em alguns casos, a leitura do array é muito mais simples, o que torna manutenção e suporte mais fácil. Porém o Array é muito utilizado quando você faz transposições de valores dentro da mesma aplicação, pois cada linguagem pode ter uma notação associativa diferente, ao contrário do JSON, que é universal.

- [Referencias de arrays](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays.asp)
- [O que é um array associativo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array)