# Warning: simplexml_load_string()

Tags: php

Olá,

Estou com esse warning no meu código:

> Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 1: parser error : Start
>   tag expected, '<' not found in /var/www/modules/search.php on line 97
>   Warning: simplexml_load_string(): {"errors":[{"error_message":"401 -
>   Unauthorized"}]} in /var/www/modules/search.php on line 97 Warning:
>   simplexml_load_string(): ^ in /var/www/modules/search.php on line 97
>   Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   /var/www/modules/search.php on line 99

Nessa linha:

```
$mp3_search = get_content("http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/?client_id=2e2135723532d1c7a5134501cb2e923c&q=" . $keyword);

if ($mp3_search)
{
    $mp3_search = simplexml_load_string($mp3_search);

    foreach ($mp3_search as $result) {
```

Comment: e qual é sua pergunta ?

Comment: editei e adicionei o $mp3_search

Comment: @feliphefelix Deu certo?

Comment: Sim, Deu a internet caiu aqui e não deu pra avisar, Ta chovendo muito.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acho que você deve estar procurando usar a função [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.file-get-contents.php) e não `get_content`.

Teu código deve ficar parecido com isto:

```
$mp3_search = file_get_contents("http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/?client_id=2e2135723532d1c7a5134501cb2e923c&q=" . $keyword);

$resultado = simplexml_load_string($mp3_search);
foreach ($resultado as $item) {
    echo $item. PHP_EOL;
}
```

Porém como os dados retornados estão em formato *json*, não é necessário a função  [`simplexml_load_string`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.simplexml-load-string.php), mas sim [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-decode.php):

```
$keyword = "Trance";
$mp3_content = file_get_contents("http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/?client_id=2e2135723532d1c7a5134501cb2e923c&q=" . $keyword);

$jsonObj = json_decode($mp3_content, true);

foreach($jsonObj as $item){
    echo $item['title']. PHP_EOL;
}
```

O segundo parâmetro da função `json_decode` é definido como *verdadeiro* para que seja possível usar o valor retornado como um [array associativo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/41140/json-%C3%A9-igual-a-um-array-associativo).

<kbd>[DEMO](http://codepad.viper-7.com/813Ifi)</kbd>