# Qual é a diferença entre chaves "{ }" e colchetes "[ ]"?

Tags: json, característica-linguagem

O formato de arquivo JSON usa dois tipos de símbolos para organizar os dados em sua estrutura, eles são:

1. Colchetes: **`[ ]`**
2. Chaves: **`{ }`**

Neles é possível inserir valores de diversos tipos, veja este exemplo de ilustração:

```
{
  "Nome": "Ana",
  "Endereco": [
                {"Rua": "Rua da boiada"}, 
                {"Cidade": "Cruzeiro"}
              ],
  "Telefones": ["31991188", "39999100"]
}
```

A minhas dúvidas estão ligadas a esses símbolos citados acima.

---

## Dúvidas

Eu gostaria de saber quais são as diferenças entre colchetes **`[ ]`** e chaves **`{ }`** e quais seriam as situações apropriadas para cada um deles?

Comment: `{}` é para criar objetos e `[]` para criar arrays.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

- `{}` servem para criar/referenciar objetos
- `[]` servem para criar/referenciar arrays

Basicamente pode dizer-se que arrays são uma lista de elementos, ordenados sem chaves especificas. Objetos são um grupo de elementos onde cada um pode ser referenciado pela sua chave.

Objetos e Arrays são tipos em JavaScript, mas têm também representação noutras linguagens. Objeto pode também chamar-se ["array associativo"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/41143/129) pois a cada valor têm associado uma chave.

Cada um desses *tipos* têm métodos próprios, qual deles usar depende do que é preciso guardar/organizar.

Se o necessário é ter uma listagem de nomes, ou sequência de numeros e é importante a ordem em que estão, então deves usar uma array. Podes ter objetos dentro de cada array. Nos objetos é prático poder chamar por chave valores do mesmo, assim a organização é por chaves e não por ordem específica.

Analizando o teu exemplo seria assim:

```
{
  "Nome": "Ana",
  "Endereco": [
                {"Rua": "Rua da boiada"}, 
                {"Cidade": "Cruzeiro"}
              ],
  "Telefones": ["31991188", "39999100"]
}
```

O teu JSON é um objeto com 3 chaves: `Nome`, `Enderenço`, `Telefones`.

A chave `Nome` tem uma *String* com o valor `Ana`.
A chave `Endereço` tem uma *Array* como valor, Array essa formada por Objetos.
A chave `Telefones` tem uma *Array* de strings.

Answer (score 9):

Chaves `{ }` delimitam a estrutura de um objeto ou seja quais propriedades/caracteristicas ele vai ter.

Colchetes `[ ]` Indica que existe mais de um elemento, é a mesma notação do array.

No exemplo da pergunta seu objeto tem três propriedades `Nome`, `Endereco` e `Telefones`..

`Endereco` possui uma coleção (array) de outros objetos `{"Rua": "Rua da boiada"}, {"Cidade": "Cruzeiro"}`

Já `Telefones` possui/aponta apenas para um array simples.

Answer (score 8):

`[]` é usado para criar *arrays* indexados (ou seja trabalham com números), sendo cada item um novo "index" dentro do array, seria quase o mesmo que `Array()`

O `{}` é um objeto, parece um pouco com *array*, mas não é, os itens dentro dele são associados por nomes (chaves), ele **não preserva** a ordem que os itens foram adicionados. Seria quase o mesmo que `new Object`