# Leitura em string formato Json para c#

Tags: c#, json

Olá, estou tendo há várias semanas como fazer para ler os valores da `string` abaixo, gostaria de ler o valor e nos sites está muito confuso nas pesquisa por que o tipo `json` que tenho começa com `{{` e tem um objeto no meio da string `[{`.
gostaria de ler o campo produção e media. Não estou achando o código correto.

Tenho a string abaixo:

```
{"d":{"media":12.108320606149539,"lote":"","Opcao":[{"__type":"Model","leitura":70,"producao":1579981660130}],"sinal":"Up"}}
```

grato pela ajuda.

Comment: Esse json não funciona. Pelo que parece ele não está completo. Tem um "{" a mais no começo, que nunca é fechado, e uma virgula onde não devia. De onde você está tirando ele?

Comment: desculpe, você tinha razão. o json não estava correto.

Comment: segue o json correto:   {"d":{"media":12.108320606149539,"lote":"","Opcao":[{"__type":"Model","leitura":70,"producao":1579981660130}],"sinal":"Up"}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá, tudo bem?

Seguinte, pega o seu json e coloca neste site: http://json2csharp.com/

Ele vai gerar as classes em c#, depois é só você fazer a deserialização.

```
var objetoRetornado = Newtonsoft.Json.Deserialize<classeGerada>(stringJson);
```

Comment: EXCELENTE, resolveu muitos problemas. Com a conversão das classes me poupou tempo de criar. Ainda tinha um problema para achar a quantidade de elementos, isso também resolveu. Obrigado a todos pela colaboração.

Answer (score 2):

Para pegar o `json` `{"d":{"media":12.108320606149539,"lote":"","Opcao":[{"__type":"Model","leitura":70,"producao":1579981660130}],"sinal":"Up"}}` e transforma-lo em objeto você pode usar o seguinte código:

obs: o `[]` indica array, você pode ler mais aqui nessa [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/173917/88361)

```
class Obj
{
    public D D { get; set; }
}

class D
{
    public string Media { get; set; }
    public string Lote { get; set; }
    public string Sinal { get; set; }
    public List<Opcao> Opcao { get; set; }
}

class Opcao
{
    public string __type { get; set; }
    public string Leitura { get; set; }
    public string Producao { get; set; }
}
```

Depois, caso seu projeto ainda não possua, baixe a biblioteca `Newtonsoft.Json` (ela está disponível via *nuget*)

e faça o `Deserialize`do json.

No exemplo abaixo salvei ele em uma string

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {            
        string json = @"{'d':{'media':12.108320606149539,'lote':'','Opcao':[{'__type':'Model','leitura':70,'producao':1579981660130}],'sinal':'Up'}}";

        Obj myObj = new Obj();

        myObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Obj>(json);

        Console.WriteLine(myObj.D.Media);
    }
}
```

É possível ver funcionando no [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/O8gL1F)

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar um `dynamic` como você já conhece a estrutura e o que quer encontrar fica muito mais simples sem precisar mapear toda a estrutura de um objeto para obter apenas o valor de alguns atributos que você sabe onde estão.

```
string json = @"{ 'd':{ 'media':12.108320606149539,'lote':'','Opcao':[{'__type':'Model','leitura':70,'producao':1579981660130}],'sinal':'Up'}}";

dynamic objeto = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(json);

//recuperando o valor de media 
var media = objeto.d.media.Value;

//veja que Opcao é um array de objetos, nesse caso pegamos primeira posição
var producao = objeto.d.Opcao[0].producao.Value;
```