# não consigo parsear json com colchetes no c#

Tags: c#, json, serialização

Estou usando a biblioteca Newtonsoft.Json.Linq para parsear json no c#.
Até agora funcionou beleza, quando tenho uma string json assim:

```
{
    'chave':'valor'
}
```

Porém quando tenho um json assim:

```
[
    {
        'chave':'valor'
    },
    {
        'chave':'valor',
        'outrachave':'outrovalor'
    }
]
```

PS: Esse json está vindo do banco de dados mysql, ele vem convertido no formato de html URI, pelo javascript, em uma coluna do mysql, eu conecto no banco com c#, recupero esse valor e uso o seguinte

```
string json = Uri.UnescapeDataString(pedido).ToString();
```

Assim eu pego o json, e tentando parsear ele assim

```
JToken result = JObject.Parse(json);
```

E o erro é o seguinte: Error reading JObject from JsonReader item is not an object

Será que essa biblioteca não aceita mesmo quando é colchete?

Comment: Já tentou "escapar", colocar um ' \ ' antes, assim ' \\[ ' ?

Comment: Oi, eu acrescentei algumas informações na pergunta...
Então eu tentei acrescentar uma barra no json, dando replace [ por \\[ e ] por \\] mas ai deu erro também, não pode ter barra antes do colchete.

Comment: Que eu sabia, `json` não aceita `'` (aspas simples) e sim `"` (aspas duplas). As IDEs sempre acusam como erro isso.

Answer (score 2):

Quando o `json` está entre **[ ]** quer dizer que é um `array`, [veja aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/173916/qual-%C3%A9-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-chaves-e-colchetes)

para isso pasta fazer `Deserialize` de uma lista

Classe com as propriedades do `json`:

```
public class Dados
{
    public string chave { get; set; }
    public string outrachave { get; set; }
}
```

`Deserialize` do `json`

```
string json = "[{'chave':'valor'},{'chave':'valor','outrachave':'outrovalor'}]";
List<Dados> itens = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Dados>>(json);
```

Coloquei no [.Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/IpuOKC) para referencia

Answer (score 0):

É porque você está tentando converter uma coleção em um único objeto.

Quando o Json tem colchetes, é necessário que o objeto de saída seja uma coleção.

```
JToken[] result = JObject.Parse(json);
```

Comment: Eu entendi sua ideia, porém o visual studio disse que não é possivel converver JObject em JToken[]
 Acho que o jeito é eu fazer uma gambiarra com split, primeiro removo os [ e ], depois dou split em }, e concateno cada um dos itens com }.

Comment: Já que você está usando Newtonsoft, experimenta fazer o seguinte: `JToken[] result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JToken[]>(json)`