# Quero transformar um texto em uma lista de dicionários

Tags: python, lista, dicionário

Estou fazendo um bot em python para o twitter que posta notícias sobre a América Latina, na hora de fazer o sistema que detecta se uma notícia é nova ou não, vou salvar as notícias que já foram postadas em um arquivo (que por enquanto é um .txt) para comparar depois com as notícias do próximo GET.
Tenho este arquivo de texto:

```
[{'pais': 'Argentina', 'titulo': 'Santistas veem vitória como resposta a críticos e exaltam Sampaoli', 'link': 'https://esportes.estadao.com.br/noticias/futebol,santistas-veem-vitoria-como-resposta-a-criticos-e-exaltam-sampaoli,70002696776'}, {'pais': 'Bolívia', 'titulo': 'Cobertura de água e esgoto no Brasil é pior que no Iraque', 'link': 'https://economia.estadao.com.br/noticias/geral,cobertura-de-agua-e-esgoto-no-brasil-e-pior-que-no-iraque,70002695633'}, {'pais': 'Brasil', 'titulo': 'Rodada dos Estaduais é marcada por homenagens à tragédia de Brumadinho', 'link': 'https://esportefera.com.br/noticias/futebol,rodada-dos-estaduais-e-marcada-por-homenagens-a-tragedia-de-brumadinho,70002696787'}, {'pais': 'Chile', 'titulo': '‘Não acredito na possibilidade de uma guerra civil na Venezuela’', 'link': 'https://internacional.estadao.com.br/noticias/geral,nao-acredito-na-possibilidade-de-uma-guerra-civil,70002695486'}]
```

E quero transformá-lo em uma lista de dicionários para que eu possa comparar os links antigos e os novos. A questão é: como fazer essa trasnformação em python?

Answer (score 2):

Uma coisa que você tem que ter em mente em relação ao JSON é que deve-se usar aspas duplas `"` ao invés de aspas simples `'`, [veja mais sobre JSON](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/173916/27190). Sendo assim, seu JSON tem que ser consertado.

De:

```
[{'pais': 'Argentina', 'titulo': 'Santistas veem vitória como resposta a críticos e exaltam Sampaoli', 'link': 'https://esportes.estadao.com.br/noticias/futebol,santistas-veem-vitoria-como-resposta-a-criticos-e-exaltam-sampaoli,70002696776'}, {'pais': 'Bolívia', 'titulo': 'Cobertura de água e esgoto no Brasil é pior que no Iraque', 'link': 'https://economia.estadao.com.br/noticias/geral,cobertura-de-agua-e-esgoto-no-brasil-e-pior-que-no-iraque,70002695633'}, {'pais': 'Brasil', 'titulo': 'Rodada dos Estaduais é marcada por homenagens à tragédia de Brumadinho', 'link': 'https://esportefera.com.br/noticias/futebol,rodada-dos-estaduais-e-marcada-por-homenagens-a-tragedia-de-brumadinho,70002696787'}, {'pais': 'Chile', 'titulo': '‘Não acredito na possibilidade de uma guerra civil na Venezuela’', 'link': 'https://internacional.estadao.com.br/noticias/geral,nao-acredito-na-possibilidade-de-uma-guerra-civil,70002695486'}]
```

Para:

```
[{"pais": "Argentina", "titulo": "Santistas veem vitória como resposta a críticos e exaltam Sampaoli", "link": "https://esportes.estadao.com.br/noticias/futebol,santistas-veem-vitoria-como-resposta-a-criticos-e-exaltam-sampaoli,70002696776"}, {"pais": "Bolívia", "titulo": "Cobertura de água e esgoto no Brasil é pior que no Iraque", "link": "https://economia.estadao.com.br/noticias/geral,cobertura-de-agua-e-esgoto-no-brasil-e-pior-que-no-iraque,70002695633"}, {"pais": "Brasil", "titulo": "Rodada dos Estaduais é marcada por homenagens à tragédia de Brumadinho", "link": "https://esportefera.com.br/noticias/futebol,rodada-dos-estaduais-e-marcada-por-homenagens-a-tragedia-de-brumadinho,70002696787"}, {"pais": "Chile", "titulo": "‘Não acredito na possibilidade de uma guerra civil na Venezuela’", "link": "https://internacional.estadao.com.br/noticias/geral,nao-acredito-na-possibilidade-de-uma-guerra-civil,70002695486"}]
```

Pois você vai receber um [erro](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39491613/5429980) sempre que tentar processar um código JSON com aspas simples `'`.

Depois de ter tratado o JSON pode fazer a leitura no seu arquivo, veja:

```
import json

with open('arq.txt') as f:    
    myjson = json.load(f)    
    print(myjson[0]['pais'])
```

Saída:

> Argentina

Use o comando `with` para [manipular arquivos](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) que é uma forma mais curta ao `try-finally`, e procure salvar na extensão `*.json` seus arquivos para evitar problemas.

Answer (score 1):

Você guardou no arquivo a representação textual em Python dos seus objetos.
Não é um formato recomendado, pois nem sempre a representação (`repr`) de um objeto vai poder reconstruí-lo.

No caso do exemplo, em que você tem apenas listas, dicionários e strings (e ainda poderia ter sem problemas números e 'None'), você pode simplesmente avaliar o conteúdo do arquivo como se fosse código Python - isso vai "compilar" esses dados como se estivessem no seu programa e retornar o objeto Python resultante. A função embutida `eval` faz isso.

Em suma, para recuperar os dados desse arquivo específicio como um objeto Python faça simplesmente:

```
 dados = eval(open("arquivo.txt").read())
```

Para continuar desenvolvendo o seu sistema, no entanto, essa não é uma forma recomendada. Além do problema de que alguns objetos não serem des-serializáveis dessa forma, o uso de `eval` na literatura não é muito recomendado - apesar de nesse caso, como o usuário do programa não deve ter acesso aos dados que vão ser processados pelo `eval` (sem ter acesso também ao código fonte), não haver o problema de segurança implicito do `eval`.

Então, aí entram as sugestões que estão pela metade em várias outras respostas aqui - numa próxima interação do programa você deve serializar esses dados com um mecânismo mais apropriado - não só com `arquivo.write(str(dados))`. Os mecanismos nativos do Python mais populares para essa serialização são o pickle e json. A diferença é mais ou menos como segue:

## json

O arquivo se mantém legível e editável direto por pessoas, num editor de textos qualquer. A desvantagem é que os tipos de dados são restritos, a não ser que você customize o serializador e desserializador json. Mas é o suficiente se você quer apenas listas, dicionários, strings números e None.

Para serializar um objeto e ler de volta usando JSON:

```
import json
with open("meu_arquivo.json", "wt") as arquivo:
     json.dump(meu_objeto, arquivo)

# para ler:

meu_objeto = json.load(open("meu_arquivo.pickle"))
```

## pickle

Pickle é interessante por que pode colocar num arquivo, e des-serializar de volta qualquer tipo de dado em que isso faça sentido (isso é: dados que não dependam do estado do programa enquanto ele está rodando, como conexões de rede, arquivos abertos, etc...). A desvantagem é que o arquivo resultante é um binário opaco, que não pode ser editado manualmente, e só pode ser extraído de volta em um aplicativo Python.
Mas você pode serializar datas, horários, conjuntos, instâncias de classes do seu próprio programa e várias outras coisas sem se preocupar com nada no código.

Para serializar um objeto e ler de volta usando Pickle:

```
import pickle
with open("meu_arquivo.pickle", "wb") as arquivo:
     pickle.dump(meu_objeto, arquivo, -1)

# para ler:

meu_objeto = pickle.load(open("meu_arquivo.pickle", "rb"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá, minha sugestão é a seguinte: se você deseja somente salvar e ler o arquivo posteriormente, deve usar pickle:

```
>>> import pickle
>>> pickle.dumps({'foo': 'bar'})
b'\x80\x03}q\x00X\x03\x00\x00\x00fooq\x01X\x03\x00\x00\x00barq\x02s.'
>>> pickle.loads(_)
{'foo': 'bar'}
```

Porém se você deseja que o arquivo seja salvo de modo legível, então use json:

```
>>> import json
>>> json.dumps({'foo': 'bar'})
'{"foo": "bar"}'
>>> json.loads(_)
{'foo': 'bar'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá,

Para resolver seu problema você teria de desenvolver um algoritmo "parecido" com o `diff`, nele você terá de checar um dicionário para ver se o tweet que você já fez está dentro dele, se sim, você faz X, senão, Y.

A minha sugestão é você usar um arquivo JSON para poder fazer o store desses dados (JSON não é nada mais que um TXT estruturado) e utiliza-lo como um dicionário dentro do Python.

Dentro do Python, a iteração no JSON poderá ser feita através do método `.items()` de um dicionário.

Answer (score -1):

Você pode usar a biblioteca `json` para transformar strings em listas, basta usar o comando:

```
import json
texto = open('arquivo.txt','r').read()
lista = json.loads(texto)
print(lista['pais'])
```

Comment: Usar a biblioteca json simplesmente para transformar strings em listas é irracional!