# Como definir nome personalizado no índice de array em Javascript?

Tags: javascript, array

*No PHP podemos utilizar:*

```
$validation = [
  200 => ['icon-check', 'The key match with the message!'],
  400 => ['icon-close', 'The key doesn\'t match with the message!'],
  403 => ['icon-close', 'Impossible to verify, the key or text can be wrong!']
];
```

*Dessa forma podemos obter o resultado utilizando `$validation[200][0]` para retornar `icon-check`.*

---

No entanto, não consigo fazer o mesmo no Javascript:

```
var validation = [
   200 => ['icon-check', 'The key match with the message!'],
   400 : ['icon-close', 'The key doesn\'t match with the message!'],
   403 = ['icon-close', 'Impossible to verify, the key or text can be wrong!']
];
```

> *Todos tipos de tentativas falham, tanto com `=>`, com `:` e com `=`.*

**Minha única alternativa foi definir o índice na variável:**

```
var validation = [];

validation['200'] = ['icon-check', 'The key match with the message!'];
validation['400'] = ['icon-close', 'The key doesn\'t match with the message!'];
validation['403'] = ['icon-close', 'Impossible to verify, the key or text can be wrong!'];
```

Entretanto, existe alguma alternativa **sem ter que repetir o `validation[XXX] = [...]`**?

Comment: Acredito que possa fazer algo semelhante com objeto: `var validation = {200: [...]}`, mas não sei se é a melhor abordagem.

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/41140

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/173916

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A maneira correta(e a única que conheço) de ter uma estrutura de dados com índice string é criando um objeto. Ex.:

```js
var validation = {
    200: ['icon-check', 'The key match with the message!'],
    400: ['icon-close', 'The key doesn\'t match with the message!'].
    403: ['icon-close', 'Impossible to verify, the key or text can be wrong!']
}
```

O problema se deve à confusão de conceito de arrays que o PHP proporciona.

Veja bem, o [PHP chama de arrays o que estruturalmente é um **ordered map**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php), então é fácil pensar que `$array = [ '400' => 'xxxxxx' ];` é um array quando na verdade é um `Map<string, string>`.

O javascript oferece uma estrututa de dados que também é um `Map`, são os `Object`, que podem ser criados na forma literal:

```js
var obj = {
    400: "xxxxxxxx",
    "403": "yyyyyy"
}
```

Ou com construtores (não é muito utilizado):

```js
var obj = new Object();
obj['400'] = "xxxx";
obj.propriedade = "yyyyy"
```

Enfim, toda a linguagem tem uma estrutura de dados indexado com strings pois é uma estrutura bem comum e útil pois a complexidade de busca por índice é geralmente *O(1)*. No python temos [dicionários](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries), no PHP os [arrays associativos](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php), no java temos [HashMaps](http://beginnersbook.com/2013/12/hashmap-in-java-with-example/), etc.

Answer (score 0):

Para atribuir uma `key` e valor utilize SEMPRE o formato json ao invés de array:

```
var obj = {
    '200': ['icon-check', 'The key match with the message!'], 
    '400': ['icon-close', 'The key doesn\'t match with the message!']
}
```

> **Mas porque fazer isso? Você me pergunta...**

Bem, você consegue até especificar um índice **numérico** para um array no javascript, porém isso não é recomendado, pois ele irá interpretar o array como se tivesse valores até aquele determinado índice, exemplo:

```
var arr = [];
arr[200] = ['icon-check', 'The key match with the message!'];
console.log(arr.length);
// Result: 201
```

Dessa forma para se ter mais flexibilidade na hora de especificar uma `key` e não correr o risco de introduzir um bug no seu código, é extremamente recomendado usar o formato **`json`**.