# Mudar a URL e o audio permanecer tocando

Tags: html, url

Estou desenvolvendo um site em PHP e Jquery onde no topo do site (presente em todas as telas) o usuário poderá clicar em play e ouvir um streaming de uma rádio ao vivo.

O problema é que ao mudar de página o audio para de tocar e a pessoa precisa dar play novamente. Vi que alguns sites conseguem contornar esse problema, mudando a URL mas o play de audio ficando sempre aberto, parece até que a URL do navegador apenas muda, mas não da um reload, um exemplo é o site da CBN: https://cbn.globoradio.globo.com/ (para testar de um play para ouvir a rádio e depois clique em algum link).

Tinha pensando em chamar o conteúdo via Ajax, mas isso seria bemmm trabalhoso, pois o site é muito grande, com notícias e tudo mais.

Qual opção tenho?

Comment: Só essa mesmo. Ou colocar seu site todo num iframe, o que parece uma péssima ideia (SEO e tudo mais).

Comment: Acho que só com iframe (como falou o @bfavaretto) ou com [SPA](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/354818/8063).