# Qual a diferença entre display:none e visibility:hidden?

Tags: css, css-display

Sei que ambos escondem o elemento, mas existe na prática alguma diferença entre:

```
#foo{
  display:none;
}
```

e

```
#foo {
  visibility:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

`display:none` retira o elemento do *layout* da página. Mas você ainda pode continuar manipulando ele no DOM.

`visibility:hidden` deixa de mostrar o elemento, ou seja, ele deixa de ser visível na página mas seu espaço continua ocupado, ou seja, o *layout* da página não é alterado por causa disto. É como você apagasse uma luz ali mas a lâmpada continua lá.

```html
1. <span style="display: none;">texto escondido</span> teste.
2. <span style="visibility: hidden;">texto escondido</span> teste.
3. <span style="opacity: 0;">texto escondido</span> teste.
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/HTML_CSS/PlayVisibility.js).

O `hidden` se assemelha ao `opacity:0`. A diferença é que o última responde a *handler events*.

## Performance

Atendendo ao comentário do Zuul eu diria que a diferença de performance é irrisória e não deveria ser levado em consideração. Se for medir o uso de `display: none` teria um ganho de performance já que ele evita que o elemento seja renderizado e é óbvio que isto poupa tempo na hora de montar a [*render tree*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/40855/101). `display: none` provavelmente causará uma nova renderização em boa parte da árvore enquanto que `visibility: hidden` renderizará apenas o local deste elemento sem interferir em toda a árvore.

Assim como sempre dizemos em programação que deve fazer o que precisa ser feito e de forma legível, não se preocupe com a performance. Então escolha qual dá o resultado esperado.

Como estamos falando de elementos visuais muita performance pode se tornar um problema para os olhos em algumas situações onde há muitas mudanças no *layout*.

Mas se tem uma animação muito complexa onde a performance pode realmente afetar, provavelmente está usando a ferramenta errada. Não se esqueça que HTML é um documento. Até dá para fazer alguma coisa mais sofisticado com ele mas usar o [`canvas`](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canvas_(HTML5)) ou um [SVG](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/SVG) pode ser uma ideia melhor à partir de um ponto.

Comment: @Zuul no CSS, o desempenho é muito mais ligado aos seletores do que às propriedades em si *(tirando algumas novas do CSS3)*, sendo que a diferença de desempenho entre as duas (`display:none` e `visibility:hidden`) só seria sentida caso existissem centenas de milhares de elementos na tela.

Comment: @Zuul o que eu acho é que não importa muito porque eles produzem resultados diferentes. Se você quer reservar o espaço no *layout*, não pode usar o `display: none`.

Comment: @Kazzkiq eu percebi que o site http://deviantart.com `display: none` em elementos fora do view-port, na tentativa de melhorar a performance, já que o sistema de páginação deles é semelhante ao do twitter, facebook, etc carregamento por scroll (AKA LazyLoad)

Comment: o exemplo da lâmpada foi ótimo

Answer (score 23):

A diferença principal é que `visibility` mantém o espaço que o elemento ocupa na página e `display: none;` não, ou seja outros elementos podem ocupar o seu lugar.

O `visibility: hidden;` é mais parecido com o `opacity: 0;` (sendo que este ultimo permite diferentes degraus de visibilidade/opacidade).

Ambos o `visibility: hidden;` e o `display: none;` não respondem a *event handlers*, enquanto que o *opacity* permite event handlers de serem chamados.

Exemplo:

```js
$('div').eq(0).css('opacity', 0);
$('div').eq(1).css('visibility', 'hidden');
$('div').eq(2).css('display', 'none');

$('div:not(:eq(3))').click(function(){
    $('div').eq(3).find('span').html(this.innerHTML);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>Teste 1</div>
<div>Teste 2</div>
<div>Teste 3</div>
<div>Clicou no elemento: <span></span></div>
```

Comment: Vale lembrar também que para tirar a visibilidade do elemento da tela, a forma semanticamente correta seria `visibility:hidden`, já que ele previne também certos eventos que o `opacity:0` não preveniria, [como o de foco, por exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/h1dwvzjf/).

Answer (score 7):

Se não me falta a memória o `display:none` retira o elemento da camada DOM, o `visibility:hidden` é a mesma coisa que `opacity:0`, apenas deixa o elemento invisível.

Answer (score 6):

Além do que já foi respondido (sobre o espaço ocupado na página, e os eventos), vale lembrar que o `display:none;`, por retirar o elemento do contexto DOM, impede que os recursos utilizados no elemento sejam carregados na memória. (ex: Imagens, fontes, etc...) Embora o conteúdo externo seja baixado para a máquina cliente, o navegador não renderiza o conteúdo, e ele não é carregado na memória...

Já com o `visibility: hidden;` a ocultação é apenas visual, e todo o conteúdo ainda está sendo renderizado pelo navegador.

Answer (score -2):

Na verdade o "visibility: none;" além de esconder, deixar invisível ele vai retirar o elemento, que na prática, de forma visual é a mesma coisa do "visibility: hidden;", mas o "none" retira o elemento e o "hidden" apena o esconde mas ele continua lá, existe uma diferença semântica na utilização dos dois elementos.