# Mostrar e esconder uma div clicando no mesmo link

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Como faço pra mostrar uma div quando clico sobre um link e voltar a esconder quando clico sobre o mesmo link?

Comment: Use [.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/).

Comment: muito bom me ajudou bastante cara

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dá uma classe a essa div e usa o [`classList.toggle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) no elemento em questão.

Dá uma olhada a este exemplo:

```js
var div = document.getElementById('minhaDiv');
var linkA = document.getElementById('linkA');
var linkB = document.getElementById('linkB');

linkA.addEventListener('click', function () {
    div.classList.toggle('display');
});

linkB.addEventListener('click', function () {
    div.classList.toggle('transicao');
});
```

```css
* {
    float: left;
    clear: both;
    padding: 20px;
}

.display {
    display: none;
}

#minhaDiv {
    transition: opacity 1s;
}

.transicao {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" id="linkA">Clica aqui para esconder sem fade (link A)</a>
<a href="#" id="linkB">Clica aqui para esconder con fade (link B)</a>

<div id="minhaDiv">Teste teste teste...</div>
```

Podes fazer isso com `display` (exemplo *link A*) ou com `opacity` (exemplo *link B*), há diferenças entre as duas.

Dá uma olhada aqui para ler mais sobre as diferenças: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/44684/129

## Com jQuery:

(caso precises mesmo... neste caso quanto menos jQuery melhor.)

#### usando [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

O `.toggle()`  mostra e esconde sem classes de CSS. Usa o *display:* `none` e `block`
**jsFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/a5mfrn7s/2/

#### usando [`toggleclass()`](http://toggleclass)

O `toggleclass()` adiciona e remove classes, como no exemplo em cima de JavaScript puro com classes de CSS (e melhor prática que o `toggle()`).
**jsFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/a5mfrn7s/1/

Comment: valeu cara muito obrigado

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

```
<a href="javascript:;" class="expander">Link</a>
<div id="minhaDiv">Div que aparece e some</div>
```

**JavaScript (slideToggle)**

```
$(function () {
    $('.expander').live('click', function () {
        $('#minhaDiv').slideToggle();
    });
});
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/felipe_douradinho/z7stu8me/1/)