# Clicar e mostrar div, clicar novamente e esconder

Tags: javascript, html, css

Galera tenho o seguinte HTML

```
<nav class="nav nav-default">
  <div class="container">
    <a href="#" class="nav-brand">Brand</a>

    <button type="button" class="nav-button">
      <span class="fa fa-navicon"></span>
    </button>

    <ul class="nav-links" id="nav-links">
      <li><a href="#">Links1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Links2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Links3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Links4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Links5</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

E o seguinte javascript:

```
$(".nav-button").click(function() {
    $("#nav-links").css("display","block");
});
```

O que acontece: Clico ele mostra os `links` mas quando clico novamente quero que esconda de novo, já testei:

[Mostrar e esconder uma div clicando no mesmo link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/71890/mostrar-e-esconder-uma-div-clicando-no-mesmo-link)

[Como esconder/mostrar uma div em HTML?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/22726/como-esconder-mostrar-uma-div-em-html)

Só que não consigo o resultado esperado. Aguardo respostas..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a função `toggle()`do jQuery:

```
$(".nav-button").click(function() {
    $("#nav-links").toggle('slow');
});
```

Comment: Obrigado, deu certo, sem querer ser preguiçoso, mas como que muda esse slow pra um que seja mais rápido? nem muito rápido mas nem muito de vagar ?

Comment: Você pode passar ele sem o 'slow' ou poderá passar ele com o 'fast' como nesse exemplo: `$("#nav-links").toggle('fast');`.

Comment: vlw deu certo. obrigado