# transition-delay css 3

Tags: css3

Tenho um efeito hover que atribui um `display: block` em um elemento. Gostaria que houvesse um delay de 2 ou 3 segundos antes que aparece o elemento que recebe o block. Sei desse transition-delay mas não estou sabendo (se é que é possível), aplicar num display block.

Answer (score 2):

A Propriedade `display` não segue a regra do `trasition-delay` já a propriedade `visibility` sim só que de uma maneira mais rígida ([Mais info aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/44678/129) sobre a diferença entre ambas propriedades).

Talvez uma solução mais visual seria aplicar `background` de for progressiva do `transparent` para a cor sólida.

Segue exemplo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .delay {
            background: tomato;

            height: 120px;
            width: 240px;

            visibility: hidden;

            transition-delay: 3s;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="submit" value="click" onClick="display()">
        <div id="delay" class="delay"></div>
        <script>
            function display() {
                var element = document.getElementById("delay");
                element.style.visibility = "visible";
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```