# Alinhamento de div dentro de html

Tags: html, css

**Tenho duas divs, quando oculto a primeira preciso que a segunda suba para o lugar dela, porém ela não se mexe, como posso fazer para ela fica no lugar da primeira div, ou seja subir?**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Segue o código:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Módulos</title>

    <style>
        table {
        }

        table-striped > tbody > tr:nth-child(odd) > th {
            background-color: red;
        }

        table-striped > tbody > tr:nth-child(odd) > td {
            background-color: white;
        }

        td {
            height: 40px;
        }

        th {
            color: white;
            background-color: #F44336;
            height: 40px;
            padding: 4px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="divconsulta" class="container-fluid" style="margin-left: -29px; margin-right: -29px">
        <!--Striped Rows-->
        <div class="row clearfix">
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <div class="card-panel" style="margin-top: -29px; ">
                    <div class="body table-responsive">
                        <table id="grid_Modulos" class="table-striped"></table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <form class="form" id="wizard_with_validation" method="POST">
        <div id="divcadastro" class="container-fluid" style="margin-left: -29px; margin-right: -29px;margin-top:0px;visibility:hidden">
            <!--Striped Rows-->
            <div class="row clearfix">
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="card-panel">
                        <div class="card" style="background: rgba(245, 245, 245, 0.6)">
                            <div class="body">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <input id="id_id" name="id_id" type="hidden" class="form-control input-style" autofocus required>
                                    <label class="label-margin-top">Descrição*</label>
                                    <input id="id_nome" name="id_nome" type="text" class="form-control input-style input-casesensitive" autofocus required>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: cara, copiei seu html/css e tem algo muito sinistro ai, melhor vc rever o css, porque é alguma coisa que vc inseriu, vou postar um html com bootstrap básico mostrando um exemplo sem sobrescrever nada do bootstrap.

Comment: Existe uma diferença entre utilizar `visibility:hidden` e `display:none`. Veja qual é a diferença [nesta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/44678/5878).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existe uma diferença entre utilizar `visibility: hidden` e `display: none` em um elemento. A diferença já foi discutida anteriormente aqui:

[Qual a diferença entre display:none e visibility:hidden?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/44678/5878)

Resumindo, utilizando o `visibility: hidden`, o espaço do elemento continua sendo ocupado, não afetando o layout da página. Se você deseja que o layout responda à omissão do elemento, use `display: none`.

**Exemplo utilizando `visibility: hidden`**

```css
.red {
  background: red;
  height: 100px;
}

.green {
  background: green;
  height: 100px;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.blue {
  background: blue;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="red"></div>
<div class="green">Este elemento será ocultado</div>
<div class="blue"></div>
```

**Exemplo utilizando `display: none`**

```css
.red {
  background: red;
  height: 100px;
}

.green {
  background: green;
  height: 100px;
  display: none;
}

.blue {
  background: blue;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="red"></div>
<div class="green">Este elemento será ocultado</div>
<div class="blue"></div>
```

> **Cuidado:** Ao definir a propriedade `display: none` utilizando estilo *inline* você não será capaz de exibir o elemento através do CSS ou do JavaScript, pois estilos *inline* possuem prioridade maior que estes, não sendo capaz de sobrescrevê-lo.

```css
#teste {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="teste" style="display: none">Stack Overflow em Português</div>
```

Leia sobre em [Qual seletor css tem prioridade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/143850/5878).

Comment: era isso mesmo. Obg

Answer (score -2):

Cara, o que pode fazer é criar uma função no javascript, por exemplo, acionada ao clicar num link, botão, etc, que oculta a primeira DIV e altera uma classe CSS da segunda DIV, mudando a posição dela na tela. De modo que ela ocupe a posição anteriormente ocupada pela outra. Isso se as duas estão visíveis ao carregar a página. Uma embaixo da outra. Mas, se uma será mostrada só quando a outra for fechada, ai a resposta já foi dada.

Comment: Pode utilizar `display: none` mesmo se os dois elementos estiverem visíveis. O layout será ajustado sozinho. Utilizar JS para isso seria gambiarra.