# Elemento com margin-left -100% continua sendo renderizado?

Tags: html, css

Elementos com `margin-left -100%` continuam sendo renderizados ou o navegador entende que eles estão fora da "área de visão" e param de usar recursos do computador?

E quando eles estão com `opacity: 0` e/ou `visibility: hidden`, isso também ocorre?

Comment: Só `display: none` para de "renderizar" *relativamente*, no DOM ainda existe e afeta alguns comportamentos, o que acontece é que ele não ocupa espaço.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Qual a diferença entre display:none e visibility:hidden?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/44678/3635)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento não acho que seja duplicata e achei essa discussão muito interessante. Tentei pesquisar se há alguma maneira de identificar com JS se o elemento está presente no DOM e sendo renderizado ou não, mas ainda não achei nada.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Só `display: none` não ocupa espaço, o resto tudo é técnica para "maquiar", claro que cada motor pode ter um esquema próprio de "otimização" para melhorar a performance conforme **"puder"**. Mas se quiser dividir e discutir cada detalhe ou técnica talvez eu retire o voto, ainda sim tenho quase certeza que só `display` tem efeito (menos na "interface DOM"). ;)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento sim, só o `display` tem efeito sobre isso, mas tem alguma forma prática da se mostrar isso além de olhar no inspetor do navegador? Tentei ver com JS mas não achei um meio de descobrir se determinado elemento estava ou não sendo renderizado . Deve haver alguma forma...

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss penso eu que renderizar seja totalmente relativo, no geral para o DOM tudo existe, o `none` só não "ocupa espaço", e quanto a renderizar é algo que pode variar de motor para motor, visando otimização dele próprio e da máquina do usuário. Eu pessoalmente aonde usei `display:none` quando havia muito conteudo percebi uma ligeira melhora (nos motores populares), mas isso não é uma afirmativa para todos motores, só analisando o source dos motores, creio eu. A resposta que já é apresentada me soa (opinião minha) como um "baita chute" sem certeza de nada.

Comment: Por isso que eu comentei que seria uma discussão interessante, pois imaginei que com JS poderia haver uma maneira de descobrir isso e até para comparar diferentes motores.

Comment: Talvez eu esteja enganado, a questão de renderização ocorre na interface que esta no núcleo, JavaScript não tem como ter acesso a isto, a não ser que exista uma API que informe, ainda sim acho que se algo assim existir não seria algo *standard*, pois cada motor gerencia a sua forma o que vai usar recursos visuais e cada um tem uma estratégia própria, resumindo a nível da camada "cliente" não creio que exista nada que possa ser feito, a nivel de núcleo e interação com as interfaces talvez seja possivel deduzir algo. Mas se desejam discutir sobre o repaint e aceleradores vou retirar meu voto.

Answer (score 2):

Sim, ele renderiza.

Prova - https://jsfiddle.net/y1h5cmtc/

Por CSS criei uma transição do `margin-left: -100%` para o `margin-left: -150%`, e ele conseguiu encontrar a diferença, que é escrita na tela por Javascript.

Portanto, existem 2 processamentos gráficos diferentes no navegador: o Renderint e o Painting.
O Painting é processado quando alguma imagem é alterada na tela, e o Rendering quando é necessário recalcular algum atributo de um elemento qualquer, seja a posição, a cor, o tamanho, etc.

Nesse caso, o Rendering recalcula a posição do elemento, mas o Painting não exibe na tela, fazendo com que seja processado apenas pelo Rendering.

Se você abrir a aba de "Performance" do DevTools do Chrome, vai perceber a diferença na execução do Painting se, na transição, substituir o `margin-left: -150%` por `margin-left: 50%`, fazendo com que exiba na tela a `div`

https://jsfiddle.net/y1h5cmtc/1/