# transition não funciona no Javascript

Tags: javascript, transição

A opção 'transition' não funciona nesse código

Oque esta errado?

Se puderem explique onde errei

Queria que ela surgisse lentamente

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>teste</title>
<style type="text/css">
 
 div{
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  border:5px solid blue;
  display: none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
 
 function chamar(){
  document.getElementById("aparecer").style.display="block"
  document.getElementById("aparecer").style.transition='all 3s'
}

</script>
<p onClick="chamar()">chamar</p>
<div id="aparecer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Várias razões para isso não funcionar:

- transições de `display: none;` para `display: block;` não são possiveis. O elemento só pode fazer transição se já estiver na página. Podes dar uma margem de 10ms, mas primeiro tem de estar na página.
- a regra `transition: all3s` tem de estar já definida no elemento e os seus valores iniciais. Chamar `transition` só com o valor final pode produzir resultados inesperados nalguns browsers

A minha sugestão é fazeres isso com uma classe de CSS somente:

```js
function chamar() {
  var div = document.getElementById("aparecer");
  div.classList.add('chamada');
}
```

```css
div {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 3s;
}

div.chamada {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 5px solid blue;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<p onClick="chamar()">Clica-me!</p>
<div id="aparecer"></div>
```

Se quiseres fazer "aparecer onde está" tens de manipular o `display` e o `opacity` um a seguir ao outro:

```js
function chamar() {
  var div = document.getElementById("aparecer");
  div.style.display = 'block';
  setTimeout(function() {
    div.style.opacity = 1;
  }, 50);
}
```

```css
div {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 5px solid blue;
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 3s;
}
```

```html
<p onClick="chamar()">Clica-me!</p>
<div id="aparecer"></div>
```

Comment: Teria como por uma animação no atributo `visibilty` na mesma situação da pergunta?

Comment: @LaércioLopes nesse caso sugiro dar uma olhada aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/44684/129 O `visibility` comporta-se como o `display`. Ou está ou não está, não permite transições.

Comment: Entedi

Desconhecia da informação do display não funcionar com transition

Entedi as 2 maneiras, mas a segunda era oque desejava...Obrigado...era tão simples

Answer (score 0):

E se no caso fosse imagem?

Queria o transition
ou que alguma forma trocasse as imagens de modo devagar...em transição

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>teste</title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
 
 function mudar(){
  document.getElementById("img").src = "imagem 2.jpg"
 }

</script>

<img id="img" src="imagem 1.jpg" onclick="mudar()">


</body>
</html>
```