# Forçar require em display:none

Tags: html, css

Tenho o seguinte html:

```
<ul class="payment-methods">
  <li class="payment-method paypal">
    <input name="payment_methods" type="radio" id="paypal">
    <label for="paypal"></label>
  </li>
  <li class="payment-method pagseguro">
    <input name="payment_methods" type="radio" id="pagseguro">
    <label for="pagseguro"></label>
  </li>
  <li class="payment-method boleto">
    <input name="payment_methods" type="radio" id="boleto">
    <label for="boleto"></label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Que mostra métodos de pagamento.

Nele, os `radio buttons` estão com `display:none` para que os `labels` sejam mostrados em seu lugar.

Existe uma forma de eu forçar que pelo menos 1 button, seja marcado mesmo que eles esteja com `display:none`?

O resultado é esse:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

CSS

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

.divCheckList .valorBool,
.divCheckList .divCheckBox {
    height: 34px;
    display: inline-block;
    border: rgb(222,222,222) 1px solid;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.divCheckList .valorBool {
    line-height: 34px;
}
.divCheckList .labelCheckBox {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 60px;
    height: 34px;
    background-color: rgb(222,222,222);
    border: none;
    border-radius: 34px;
    -webkit-transition: .4s;
    transition: .4s;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.divCheckList .labelCheckBox:before {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 26px;
    height: 26px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    border-radius: 50%;
    content: "";
    margin: 4px;
    -webkit-transition: .4s;
    transition: .4s;
}
.divCheckList .divCheckBox .checkBox:checked + .labelCheckBox {
    background-color: blue;
}
.divCheckList .divCheckBox .checkBox:checked + .labelCheckBox:before {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
    -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
    transform: translateX(26px);
}
```

Comment: E se colocar a propriedade `checked` o que acontece?

Comment: Não há como colocar checked em dislay:none. Não encontra o objeto!

Answer (score 2):

Acredito que o objetivo é interagir o `radio` junto com a imagem que é exibida, fazendo com que a imagem tenha o comportamento do `radio`. Se for, você pode, ao invés de definir `display: none`, que remove o elemento do DOM, utilizar `visibility: hidden`, que apenas o oculta.

[Qual a diferença entre display:none e visibility:hidden?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/44678/5878)

A questão é que o espaço ocupado na tela pelo `input` não é compensado ao ocultá-lo e, por isso, é necessário também definir a posição do mesmo como absoluta; desta forma, você retirará o elemento do *flow* natural de renderização e o seu espaço na tela será compensado.

Veja um exemplo:

```css
label {
  cursor: pointer;
}

label > input {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
}

label > input:checked + img {
  border: solid 1px red;
}
```

```html
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="avatar" value="1" checked>
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" alt="">
</label>
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="avatar" value="2">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" alt="">
</label>
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="avatar" value="3">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" alt="">
</label>
```

Comment: entendi e gostei da ideia. Porém o require não está funcionando. Está passando direto mesmo não marcado!

Comment: @CarlosRocha você deve ter feito errado, pois testei aqui e funciona normalmente. Reproduza seu problema no https://jsfiddle.net e mande o link.

Comment: Acho que é isso: O código completo está na pergunta:
https://jsfiddle.net/tzLvfokq/

Comment: Mas você não definiu o campo como `required`.

Comment: Vê em funcionando com required e e passando do mesmo jeito: http://www.hotplateprensas.com.br/estilos/

Comment: Sem selecionar a forma de pagamento, o formulário não é submetido. Não é isso que precisa?

Comment: isso. Porém o require não está funcionando nas opções de pagamento. Note que mesmo com as alterações o require não funciona. Passa direto para o próximo campo do formulário. Por isso coloquei os arquivos na web e o link. Para ficar melhor de ver o erro.

Comment: O que seria "passa para o próximo campo"? Você diz sobre a mensagem de erro? Se sim, de fato ela não aparece, pois o campo está oculto, mas o `required` funciona, pois o formulário não é submetido sem selecionar a forma de pagamento. Se você deseja que apareça uma mensagem de erro, deverá fazer isso manualmente.

Comment: Observe que abaixo das opções de pagamento aparecer o primeiro type text. E, ao clicar no segundo botão Enviar, sim, clique no segundo pois só ele é type submit, o required do type text é acionado Removi os outros botões

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65429/discussion-between-anderson-carlos-woss-and-carlos-rocha).

Comment: Debugando no chrome achei isso: An invalid form control with name='payment_methods' is not focusable.

Answer (score 0):

Coloque o width e o height  com valor "0", assim ele não vai ser "display:none" e não vai aparecer da mesma forma.

```
  width:0;
  height:0;
```

Comment: Eu tive outra ideia e gostaria da opinião de vocês: E se, ao invés de fazer require no input, colocar no label alguma coisa equivalente? Sem chances né?

Comment: você pode usar jquery colocando evento click no label, você cria um input hidden, então ao clicar no label o evento click envia o valor para o input hidden e assim você pode ate deixar um valor padrão no campo.

Comment: Não funcionou pois mostra o input no tamanho real.