# O que está errado nessa extensão Chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, json, google-chrome-extensão

Fiz uma pequena extensão em Chrome, e ela não está funcionando corretamente. Minha extensão simplesmente randomiza uma palavra entre uma daquelas `randomVals` e exibe. Gostaria que me ajudassem a saber o que está errado nela.
Este é o código:

**Manifest**

```
{
  "name": "RandomHype",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "RandomHype official Extensions.",
  "browser_action": {
     "popup": "rh.html"
  }
}
```

**`rh.html`**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="typeget.css">
    <script>
    function getRandomInt(min, max) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    }
    var randomVals = ['Play BTD5',
        'Code',
        'Watch a video',
        'Play Chess',
        'Study',
        'Chat (Skype)',
        'Check Twitter',
        'Check the news on Tecmundo',
        'Talk about SW'
    ];
    var r_i = getRandomInt(0, randomVals.length - 1);
    document.getElementById('doThing').innerHTML = randomVals[r_i];
</script>
  </head>
<body>
<center>
  <h3>I should</h3><br><h1><p id="doThing">Code</p>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: O ideal é você colocar *aqui* o seu código sem a gente precisar ir em outro site pra ver. Pode usar o Stack Snippet usando o botão "Trecho JS/HTML/CSS" da barra de edição. E também não pode pedir pra gente revisar todo o seu código procurando o erro. O que que dá errado? O que tentou fazer para consertar? Fez debug (`console.log`)?

Comment: Desculpe, sou bem novo aqui.

Comment: Deu errado: A extensão é adicionada, mas o PopUP não abre quando clico. O que tentei: Mudar algo do HTML e do .json mas não consegui.

Comment: Tá melhorando :) Imagino que o primeiro trecho é o Manifest e o segundo é o popup `rh.html`.... é isso? Se puder explicar também o que sua extensão faz ia ser legal.

Comment: Sim, Minha extensão simplesmente randomiza uma palavra entre uma daquelas palavras e exibe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primeiramente, há uma tag `h1` não fechada.

Outro problema é que seu *manifest* está incorreto. Ao invés de `popup`, utilize `default_popup`:

```
{
  "name": "RandomHype",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "RandomHype official Extensions.",
  "browser_action": {
        "default_popup": "rh.html"
    }
}
```

Continuando, se a sua intenção é alterar o conteúdo de `<p id="doThing">...</p>` com um valor pré-definido cada vez que o *script* for executado, você precisa colocar esse script depois do elemento.

Abrindo o console, você verá o seguinte erro:

> TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null

Isto é porque dentro do `<head>`, especificamente nessa linha `document.getElementById('doThing')` você tenta obter um elemento que ainda não <s>existe</s> foi carregado.

#### Você pode...

Colocar esse script no final do documento, antes de fechar a tag `<body`:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="typeget.css">
</head>

<body>
  <center>
    <h3>I should</h3>
    <br>
    <h1><p id="doThing">Code</p></h1>
  </center>
  <script>
    function getRandomInt(min, max) {
      return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    }
    var randomVals = ['Play BTD5',
      'Code',
      'Watch a video',
      'Play Chess',
      'Study',
      'Chat (Skype)',
      'Check Twitter',
      'Check the news on Tecmundo',
      'Talk about SW'
    ];

    var r_i = getRandomInt(0, randomVals.length - 1);
    document.getElementById('doThing').innerHTML = randomVals[r_i];
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

---

Executar o script quando o [**DOM**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40852/4808) estiver pronto:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="typeget.css">

  <script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

      function getRandomInt(min, max) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
      }
      var randomVals = ['Play BTD5',
        'Code',
        'Watch a video',
        'Play Chess',
        'Study',
        'Chat (Skype)',
        'Check Twitter',
        'Check the news on Tecmundo',
        'Talk about SW'
      ];


      var r_i = getRandomInt(0, randomVals.length - 1);
      document.getElementById('doThing').innerHTML = randomVals[r_i];

    }, false);
  </script>

</head>

<body>
  <center>
    <h3>I should</h3>
    <br>
    <h1><p id="doThing">Code</p></h1>
  </center>
</body>

</html>
```

---

Mais informações sobre o `DOMContentLoaded` [nesse link](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded).

Estes exemplos foram para rodar o *snippet*, em extensões do Google Chrome o arquivo Javascript deve ser criado a parte e não *inline* no documento HTML. Crie um arquivo `popup.js` (por exemplo), coloque o seu código Javascript nele e apenas referencie no HTML:

```
<script src='popup.js'></script>
```

Comment: OK, parece que isso agora está funcionando. Porém, continuo sem conseguir abrir o popup

Comment: @MucaP Editei a minha resposta.

Comment: Obrigado, tinha dado um erro que o JS não pode estar no arquivo html, mas resolvi importando o script, pronto, respondido. Se quiser editar a resposta para futuras pessoas, é só que tem que criar outro arquivo de script