# É possivel fazer um IF com javascript direto no html?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho um botão que desejo mostrar somente se a pessoa logada for um administrador. Mas tem que ser em JS.

Em PHP, eu faria assim:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
</head>

<body>

    <?php if (loginPermissoes == "admin"){ ?>
        <button id="btnOcorrenciaConcluida">Marcar como concluído</button>
    <?php }else{ ?>

    <?php } ?>


</body>
</html>
```

**Como faço isso em Javascript ou com jQuery?**

Seria assim?

```
<script> if (loginPermissoes == "admin"){ </script>
    <button id="btnOcorrenciaConcluida">Marcar como concluído</button>
<script> }else{ </script>

<script> } </script>
```

Comment: <script> seu código vai aqui.</script>

Comment: @Highlander sei que é no dentro do ``<script>``...rsrsrs, mas é feito na mesma estrutura do meu exemplo php acima?

Comment: E como você vai fazer o JS saber se é admin ou não?

Comment: @bigown quando a pessoa logar fica registrado na variável ``loginPermissoes``.

Comment: O código em JS não funciona, a lógica das duas linguagens é completamente diferente. PHP cria textos para mandar para o navegador, JS manipula a página existente através do [DOM](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40852/101). Mas como o JS saberá o valor dessa variável? precisa saber como pretende resolver isto. Dependendo do caso, não faz sentido resolver isto no JS. Se fizer sentido, talvez não seja só o caso de mexer nisto.

Comment: Eu até poderia responder como fazer a exibição mas precisaria saber de onde vem a informação se é admin ou não. Sem isto, é um problema abstrato e não real, aí fica difícil responder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fazer isto somente no *front-end*, não trará segurança nenhuma. Qualquer pessoa má intencionada poderá controlar as coisas desde que tenha o minimo de conhecimento, de qualquer maneira você pode usar combinado com *css*, assim:

> Nota: só usei o `window.prompt` como exemplo, você pode controlar a variável como quiser.

```js
var btnOcorrenciaConcluida = document.getElementById("btnOcorrenciaConcluida");
var permissoesLogin = window.prompt("Qual permissão?");

if (permissoesLogin == "admin") {
   btnOcorrenciaConcluida.className = "";
} else {
   btnOcorrenciaConcluida.className = "hide";
}
```

```css
.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<button id="btnOcorrenciaConcluida" class="hide">Marcar como concluído</button>
```

O codigo todo fica assim:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
    .hide {
         display: none;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="btnOcorrenciaConcluida" class="hide">Marcar como concluído</button>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var btnOcorrenciaConcluida = document.getElementById("btnOcorrenciaConcluida");
        var permissoesLogin = window.prompt("Qual permissão?");

        if (permissoesLogin == "admin") {
           btnOcorrenciaConcluida.className = "";
        } else {
           btnOcorrenciaConcluida.className = "hide";
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Esta é uma solução, não sei se resolve o problema do AP, mas pelo menos atende os requisitos postados.

Answer (score 2):

Eu não entendo bem o que você quer. Você quer usar variáveis feitas no PHP pelo JS? Sem usar o PHP no meio? Então acho que você quer usar [Ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX).

Basicamente eu já fiz uma velha função para fazer uma requisição **Ajax**. Você pode usar elas:

```
function Get(t,e,n){var s=new XMLHttpRequest;s.onreadystatechange=function(){4==s.readyState&&200==s.status?(e(s.responseText),s=void 0):s.status>=500&&(s=void 0,n(0))},t+=t.indexOf("?")>-1?"&tsmp="+Date.now():"?tsmp="+Date.now(),s.open("GET",t,!0),s.send()}
function Post(t,e,n,o){var s=new XMLHttpRequest;s.onreadystatechange=function(){4==s.readyState&&200==s.status?(n(s.responseText),s=void 0):s.status>=500&&(s=void 0,o(0))},t+=t.indexOf("?")>-1?"&tsmp="+Date.now():"?tsmp="+Date.now(),s.open("POST",t,!0),s.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded"),s.send(e)}
```

(b, bem, eu já tinha comprimido antes)

E aí, bem, você precisa de um arquivo PHP que dá echo em algum valor do usuário. Como exemplo:

```
<?php (...) echo Usuario["privilegio"];?>
```

Então, usando a função `Get` acima você pode pegar esse valor que vai sair do arquivo PHP. São requiridos 3 argumentos: `[URL do arquivo]`, `[função de sucesso]` e `[função de erro]`

```
Get("http://localhost:8000/valor.php",function(e){
      alert("Valor: "+e);//alerta "Valor: Usuario[\"privilegio\"]" do arquivo PHP
      if(parseInt(e)==0){//se o privilégio do usuário é igual à 0
         //yay
      }
    },function(){
      alert("Falhou na requisição. Pode ser um delay?")
    }
)
```

Lembre-se de fazer a mesma condifição `if` para o arquivo de ação do administrador.

Comment: A solução é interessante, mas usa PHP que ele diz não poder usar. Eu sei que não é fácil resolver isto, mas a pergunta é clara nesse sentido.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var permissoesLogin = '<?php echo $loginPermissoes; ?>';
    if (permissoesLogin == "admin") {
         //todo
    } else {
         //todo
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Não posso usar PHP, tem que ser tudo JS.

Comment: Sua validação não é feita `server-side`? Você trás a resposta do `server` pro `client` e faz o tratamento.

Comment: Isso, esta solução dá na mesma, se for para fazer assim, é melhor resolver tudo em PHP. Embora @Tiago que mal lhe pergunte, há um motivo para não usar o PHP?

Comment: Amigo @Tiago, é impossivel - eu pelo menos desconheço - você tratar valores via javascript de valores preenchidos no `server`. Se você quiser usar javascript, beleza... porém a variável `permissoesLogin` tem que receber o que vier do `server` (atribuação feita no `server`).

Comment: @bigown, estou apredendo a usar o intelxdk, só aceita html5 e js.

Comment: Então @MarllonNasser o problema é que sua resposta não resolve o problema dele. Na verdade nem faz nada útil mesmo que o PHP pudesse ser usado. Ainda que alguém achou que sim. Eu evito negativar coisa assim, mas esta resposta não faz nada.

Comment: @bigown, eu entendi a pergunta da forma como está sendo feita: "Como fazer tal validação via javascript/jquery?". Postei uma das N formas de se fazer via javascript. rs... mas aparentemente ele quer tratar valores do server no client sem colocar no client o que vem do servidor... isso pra mim é impossivel. se ele descobrir, gostaria muito de saber rs. Enfim, acho que ele quer fazer o impossível.

Comment: Mas você usou PHP. E não exibiu nada.

Answer (score -1):

você não vai conseguir desviar o fluxo com o javascript desta forma que você fez.

você pode inserir o html dentro do javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var btn = '<button id="btnOcorrenciaConcluida">Marcar como concluído</button>';
if (permissoesLogin == "admin") {
     // comando para escrever o btn em alguma tag html
} else {
     // faz outra coisa...
}
```

Comment: E de onde vem essa variável `permissoesLogin`? Este código também não faz nada útil.

Comment: ele informou ela no código que ele deu de exemplo. A questão aparentemente fala sobre o desvio de fluxo com o javascript. Se a questão for sobre autenticação de usuários, acredito que não há como fazer com javascript

Comment: Eu não negativei nada. Mas sua resposta não responde o que foi perguntado, e quem negativou também acha isto. Diga de onde vem esta variável e faça alguma coisa dentro do `if` e aí sua resposta estará respondendo a pergunta de fato.

Comment: @bigown pra que ficar negativando assim? a minha pergunta responde exatamente o que ele pediu. Ele não disse que era problemas de validação de usuário. Ele trata a variável permissoesLogin como ele quiser...

Comment: essa variável vem do código que ele informou. E ele trata ela como ele quiser. Se o problema é autenticação client-side, deveria ter especificado isso na pergunta. É impossível, até onde eu sei, fazer autenticação de usuários do lado do cliente. O problema dele é controle de fluxo, pelo menos é isso que foi explicitado na pergunta.