# Exibir mensagem e esconder em alguns segundos

Tags: jquery, css, css-transições

Como fazer para mostrar uma notificação ao entrar no site e sumir depois de alguns segundos, com `jQuery`?

Tentei algo mas não consegui.

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/sunnypmody/XDaEk/

Código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>haxP v2</title>
      <link rel="shortcut icon" href="./favicon.png">
      <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
   <body bgcolor="#3CB371"/>
      <center>
         <style>body {left:0;line-height:200px;margin:auto;margin-top:-100px;position:absolute;top:50%;width:100%;color:#ffffff;font-family:Constantia,"Lucida Bright","DejaVu Serif",Georgia,serif;font-size:56px;}#frase{left:0;line-height:200px;margin:auto;margin-top:-100px;position:absolute;top:65%;width:87%;;font-family:Constantia,"Lucida Bright","DejaVu Serif",Georgia,serif;font-size:8px;}#rodape{left:0;line-height:200px;margin:fixed;margin-top:0px;position:absolute;bottom:0;top:110%;width:100%;;font-family:Constantia,"Lucida Bright","DejaVu Serif",Georgia,serif;font-size:10px;}</style>
         </head>
         <body>
            <div id="texto">
               <font face="Pacifico">Welcome Underground</font>
            </div>
            <div id="frase">
               Cada sonho que você deixa pra trás, é um pedaço do seu futuro que deixa de existir.
            </div>
            <div id="rodape">
               Powered by <b><font face="Pacifico" size="2">Cruz</font></b>
            </div>
   </body>
</html>
</center>
```

Comment: Bem vindo ao sopt. O que você já tentou, não tentativa alguma no código apresentado.

Comment: O problema é que eu não consigo encaixar Esse Códico: http://jsfiddle.net/sunnypmody/XDaEk/

Comment: Pode adicionar o link desse jsfiddle na pergunta? Clique em [edit]

Comment: JS Fiddle Adicionado

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Exemplo didático:

```js
// Iniciará quando todo o corpo do documento HTML estiver pronto.
$().ready(function() {
 setTimeout(function () {
  $('#foo').hide(); // "foo" é o id do elemento que seja manipular.
 }, 2500); // O valor é representado em milisegundos.
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="foo">Foo Bar</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

> mostrar uma notificação ao entrar no site e sumir depois de alguns segundos

Usando o Exemplo que você mesmo deu :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){  // A DIFERENÇA ESTA AQUI, EXECUTA QUANDO O DOCUMENTO ESTA "PRONTO"
  $( "div.success" ).fadeIn( 300 ).delay( 1500 ).fadeOut( 400 );
});

$( "#success-btn" ).click(function() {
  $( "div.success" ).fadeIn( 300 ).delay( 1500 ).fadeOut( 400 );
});

$( "#failure-btn" ).click(function() {
  $( "div.failure" ).fadeIn( 300 ).delay( 1500 ).fadeOut( 400 );
});

$( "#warning-btn" ).click(function() {
  $( "div.warning" ).fadeIn( 300 ).delay( 1500 ).fadeOut( 400 );
});
```

```css
.alert-box {
 padding: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 4px;  
}

.success {
    color: #3c763d;
    background-color: #dff0d8;
    border-color: #d6e9c6;
    display: none;
}

.failure {
    color: #a94442;
    background-color: #f2dede;
    border-color: #ebccd1;
    display: none;
}

.warning {
    color: #8a6d3b;
    background-color: #fcf8e3;
    border-color: #faebcc;
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
    <button id="success-btn">Success</button>
    <button id="failure-btn">Failure</button>
    <button id="warning-btn">Warning</button>
</p>
<div class="alert-box success">Successful Alert !!!</div>
<div class="alert-box failure">Failure Alert !!!</div>
<div class="alert-box warning">Warning Alert !!!</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Não chega a ser necessário Javascript para isto, pode usar somente as [animações](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation) das CSS visto que você quer exibir a notificação assim que o usuário entrar no site, não quando a página estiver completamente carregada ou o [DOM](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40852/4808) estiver pronto.

Crie sua própria regra de comportamento com [@keyframes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes), por exemplo:

```
@keyframes hide {
  from { opacity: 1 }
  to   { opacity: 0 }
}
```

E então usar essa regra para [animar](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation) o elemento contendo a notificação.

Com a propriedade [animation-delay](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/animation-delay) você pode definir o tempo para a animação começar, se não quiser que ela ocorra instantaneamente, quando o usuário entrar na página. Por meio de [animation-duration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/animation-duration), define-se a duração que deve acontecer o que foi especificado na *keyframe*.

Para manter o estilo final (`opacity: 0`) no elemento alvo da animação, existe a propriedade [`animation-fill-mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode) que pode receber o valor `forwards`. E você terá isto:

```css
@keyframes hide {
  from { opacity: 1 }
  to   { opacity: 0 }
}

div {
  animation: hide 2s 2s forwards
}
```

```html
<div>Notificação de 2 segundos...</div>
```

Aplicando isto ao fiddle que foi postado nos comentários, ficaria assim:

```css
@keyframes hide {
  from { opacity: 1 }
  to   { opacity: 0 }
}

.alert-box {
  animation: hide 2s 2s forwards;
  padding: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.success {
  color: #3c763d;
  background-color: #dff0d8;
  border-color: #d6e9c6
}
```

```html
<div class="alert-box success">Successful Alert !!!</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Se for em Bootstrap você pode usar o **window.setTimeout.** 
é muito mais fácil. 
Abraço!

```
<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
  <strong>Success!</strong> You have been signed in successfully!
</div>

<script >window.setTimeout(function () {
    $(".alert").fadeTo(500, 0).slideUp(500, function () {
        $(this).remove();
    });
}, 4000);
//# sourceURL=pen.js
</script>
```

Comment: Não precisa utilizar bootstrap para utilizar window.setTimeout

Comment: Eu sei! apenas dei uma sugestão, e nessa sugestão utilizei o Bootstrap como exemplo, talvez alguém que esteja utilizando essa biblioteca possa precisar, mais acho que o senhor não entendeu muito bem hehhehe Abraço!