# O que é e quais são as diferenças entre DOM, Window e Screen?

Tags: javascript

Li algumas definições desses objetos  e no meu entendimento `window` é a primeira coisa que o navegador carrega e o objeto `DOM` está contido nele, sendo o `DOM` a representação do `HTML`.

Mas ainda não me sinto confiante a ponto de falar desses objetos com propriedade, será vocês conseguiriam me ajudar a defini-los de forma mais precisa?

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40852/101

Comment: Opa eu não tinha achado essa pergunta, obrigado pelo link

Comment: @CaiqueRomero veja várias coisas sobre DOM na lista relacionada ao lado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em uma abordagem simples, `window` é um objeto de janela `DOM`, uma propriedade global que fornece métodos referente a raiz do modelo, 'por isso window', é dentro dele que fica o `DOM`.

[window MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window)

já screen é um dos métodos que window fornece, basicamente guarda informações das dimensões da janela.

[window.screen MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/screen)

DOM é um assunto longo e já foi tratado aqui.