# Quando a pessoa escolher algo no select exibir uma imagem do lado do formulario

Tags: javascript, html, css

Eu estou fazendo um formulário no qual o usuário vai escolher uma imagem de fundo, queria que quando ela escolhesse essa imagem no select exibisse do lado ou em baixo uma miniatura dela, procurei bastante na internet mas não achei nada que possa me ajudar. Meu formulário está bem básico até o momento:

```
    <form action="gerador.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
  <fieldset>
    <legend style="text-align: center;">Gerador de banner</legend>
    <!--<legend><span class="number">1</span>E-mail:</legend>
    <input type="text" name="email">-->
    <legend><span class="number">2</span>Data:</legend>
    <input type="date" name="data">
    <legend><span class="number">3</span>Local:</legend>
    <input type="text" name="local" maxlength="78">
    <legend><span class="number">4</span>Horario:</legend>
    <input type="text" name="horario">
    <legend><span class="number">5</span>Background:</legend>
    <select name="bg">
        <option selected="" disabled="">Selecione o background...</option>
        <option value="bg1.png">Background 1</option>
        <option value="bg2.png">Background 2</option>
    </select>
    <legend><span class="number">6</span>Logo Universidade:</legend>
    <input name="arquivo" type="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="Gerar" />
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Agradeço desde já

Comment: 1 - Capture o evento `change` do seu elemento `<select>`; 2 - Busque pelo valor selecionado; 3 - Crie um elemento `<img>` (ou selecione um existente do DOM); 4 - Define o valor de  `src` da imagem como o valor selecionado; 5 - Adicione a imagem ao DOM se ela ainda não estiver nele. Quer tentar? Boa sorte.

Comment: entendi a logica, fiquei só com 2 duvidas, o q é esse DOM rs e como eu faço pra sumir a imagem caso escolher outra? sei que posso da um hide no elemento, mas caso eu tiver 10 imagens eu vou ter q dar hide em todas no final do código?

Comment: [O que é DOM, Render Tree e Node?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40852/5878)

Comment: vlw man, vou tentar aprender mais sobre ajax e js pois os últimos projetos está osso, Obrigado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crie um event listener no seu select. Usando `change` como gatilho, a função declarada como callback será invocada toda vez que o valor do seu select for alterado. Então é só alterar a url fonte do seu elemento que contém a imagem de preview.

```js
document.getElementById('img_select').addEventListener('change', function() {
  document.getElementById('img_preview').src = this.value
})
```

```html
<select name="bg" id="img_select">
    <option selected disabled>Selecione o background...</option>
    <option value="https://opengameart.org/sites/default/files/backgrounddetailed3.png">Background 1</option>
    <option value="https://opengameart.org/sites/default/files/backgrounddetailed1.png.preview.jpg">Background 2</option>
</select>
<img id="img_preview">
```

Comment: deu certinha para o que eu precisava, me salvou, obrigadão.