# o que é DOM e sua relação com JS?

Tags: javascript

Estudando javasrcript, sempre leio sobre DOM, como acessar, como alterar, mas nunca ficou claro exatamente o que é e qual sua utilidade

Comment: Does this answer your question? [O que é DOM, Render Tree e Node?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/40852/o-que-%c3%a9-dom-render-tree-e-node)