# Estou tendo um erro Cannot read property 'classList' of null at iniciaModal, mas não sei resolver

Tags: javascript, html, classes, popup, id

É o seguinte, eu sou leigo em programação, porém estou fazendo um site, e no caso, só falta fazer um modal pop-up, para a pessoa agendar um horário num salão de cabeleireiro. Eu estou seguindo o seguinte vídeo tutorial: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fu-enUG2VEE".

Já fiz a parte do HTML e do CSS, definindo as classes, id, e as estilizações, porém nessa parte do JavaScript estou tendo esse erro do `Cannot read property 'classList' of null at iniciaModal`

Eu segui perfeitamente o tutorial, claro respeitando o jeito do meu projeto, do tipo, meu CSS e JavaScript são externos do HTML, todos os arquivos que uso no projeto do site, estão na mesma pasta e linkados no código HTML.

Vou colocar resumidamente a parte dos códigos:

**HTML**

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="index2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="modal-promocao" class="modal-container">
        <div class="modal">
            <button class="fechar">X</button>
            <h3>Solicitação de Agendamento</h3>
            <form>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Nome">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Número">
                <button>Manhã</button><button>Tarde</button>
                <input type="button" value="Enviar">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function iniciaModal(modalID) {
    const modal = document.getElementById(modalID);
    modal.classList.add('mostrar');
}

iniciaModal('modal-promocao');
```

Se alguém puder me explicar de uma maneira simples, pois não sou muito conhecedor de todos os códigos. O objetivo é apenas fazer esse pop-up funcionar de maneira correta e entender o por quê de aparecer esse erro do `Cannot read property 'classList' of null at iniciaModal`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note que o seu *script* executa a função `iniciaModal` imediatamente (assim que esse trecho é avaliado).

Note também que você inseriu o `<script>` no `<head>`, o que evidencia que o *script* terá sido executado antes do DOM estar pronto para a manipulação (ou sequer carregado).

Isso significa que quando o *runtime* do JavaScript executar a função `iniciaModal`, o elemento de ID `modal-promocao` não estará "pronto" para a manipulação, o que fará a função `getElementById` retornar `null` (já que o elemento que ela procurou "ainda não existe").

E como já sabemos, ao tentar acesar uma propriedade de `null` (como você tentou fazer com `classList`), o JavaScript lança um erro:

```js
const elm = document.getElementById('eu-nao-existo');

console.log(elm); // null

// Lançará um erro:
// Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null
elm.classList;
```

Para resolver isso, você precisa garantir que o elemento que você busca está "pronto para ser manipulado" ao tentar buscá-lo usando `getElementById`.

Uma opção é você incluir o *script* antes do fechamento de `<body>`, assim:

```html
...
<body>
  ...

  <script type="text/javascript" src="index2.js"></script>
</body>
```

Assim você garante que todo o HTML terá sido devidamente carregado (e pronto para manipulação) antes do *script* ser executado.

Uma outra opção é só executar o *script* perante a emissão do evento [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded), que também garante a possibilidade de manipulação do DOM. Nesse caso, você não precisa alterar a estrutura do seu HTML, apenas escutar o evento. Assim:

```
function iniciaModal(modalID) {
  const modal = document.getElementById(modalID);
  modal.classList.add('mostrar');
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  iniciaModal('modal-promocao');
});
```

Note que agora a função `iniciaModal` só será executada quando o evento `DOMContentLoaded` for disparado.

Comment: Eu ainda sou bem novato em programação, então não entendi muito bem o que significa muito esse DOM, mas isso depende dos meus estudos, algum dia eu aprendo certinho, coloquei o script antes de fechar o body e resolveu o problema, obrigado pela ajuda Luiz!

Comment: @RamonRossini, esta pergunta pode ajudar a entender: [O que é DOM, Render Tree e Node?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40852/69296)