# Como verificar se os quatro primeiros caracteres de uma string correspondem a 'www.'?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Qual a melhor maneira de verificar isso? De forma mais simples e com melhor performance.

Só consegui imaginar fazer assim:

```
var string = "www.google.com";

if(string[0] == "w" && string[1] == "w" && string[2] == "w" && string[3] == "."){
   // string começa com www.
}
```

Comment: `string.substring(0, 4) == "www."`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

O código fica com uma aparência melhor (mais legível) se você olhar os 4 caracteres de uma vez:

```
if(string.substr(0, 4) === "www.") {

}
```

Ou

```
if(string.substring(0, 4) === "www.") {

}
```

Os dois métodos fazem basicamente a mesma coisa, porém o primeiro recebe o índice inicial e o comprimento, enquanto o segundo recebe o índice inicial e o final (não inclusivo).

Mais um método, que recebe dois índices e extrai até antes do índice final:

```
if(string.slice(0, 4) === "www.") {

}
```

Em termos de performance, [os 3 métodos parecem equivalentes](http://jsperf.com/sopt-46342) (no V8/Chrome).

---

Além desses três, há também o teste via expressão regular, como [sugerido pelo QMechanic73](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/46354/74), e o `indexOf`, [sugerido pelo Sergio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/46364/74). Ainda é possível tomar outros caminhos, como comparar cada caractere obtendo-os via `String.prototype.charAt`.

Comparando com esse tipo de solução, **o seu teste original, que verifica cada caractere individual, está [bem mais rápido](http://jsperf.com/sopt-46342/8)** que qualquer outro (no meu browser). Isso me surpreendeu. Comparando rapidamente os métodos de extração na especificação da linguagem, não vi nenhum motivo óbvio para isso. Provavelmente o culpado pela demora dos outros métodos é a criação de um *wrapper object* do tipo `String`, e posterior chamada de método nesse objeto (incluindo verificação da [cadeia de protótipos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/15247/74)).

Comment: Se a string não tiver o tamanho mínimo esperado (suponha que seja somente "ww") o código original do OP vai dar erro, certo? E no caso de cada um desses métodos, como é tratado o *out of bounds* no Javascript...? Se eles forem robustos, é mais um benefício desse uso.

Comment: Não vai dar erro tentar acessar um índice que não existe na string, simplesmente retorna `undefined` @LuizVieira.

Answer (score 9):

Uma outra alternativa é o método [`RegExp.test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)

```js
var endereco = "www.google.com.br";

if (/^www\./.test(endereco))
    console.log("Começa com www.");
else
    console.log("Não começa com www.");
```

A expressão `^www\.` vai corresponder ao caracteres `www.` no início da *string*. Sobre a performance, o código postado na pergunta parece ser o mais mais rápido, como pode ser visto [**nesse comparativo** criado pelo @bfavaretto](https://jsperf.com/sopt-46342/8).

Comment: Mais rápido provavelmente por não ter que criar uma cópia de parte da string todas as vezes, como deve ocorrer com o `substring`. Seria legal comparar com o método do @Sergio - suponho que este também não crie cópia da string e o código é mais simples que o original do AP.

Comment: @Caffé Existe sim cópia de parte da string. O que não existe é a criação de um objeto tipo `String` para que os métodos possam ser invocados (veja minha resposta atualizada para mais detalhes).

Answer (score 6):

Uma outra variante ainda nõ referida para verificar se a string começa com esses 4 caracteres:

```
if (string.indexOf("www.") == 0) // caso sim
else // caso não
```

O `.indexOf()` verifica a posição de `"www."` na variável `string`. Se o resultado do `.indexOf()`, fôr `0` então a string começa com `"www."`.

Answer (score 3):

O que o @QMechanic73  falou esta correto, apesar do seu codigo parecer um pouco mais extenso ele e mais rápido do que os demais, apenas uma dica simples para melhorar um pouco a performance, utilize  `===` em vez de `==`.

Veja a diferença em: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Igualdade

A [performance varia por navegador](http://jsperf.com/jscomp14), no firefox o `==` foi mais rápido que o `===` e no google chrome foi o `===`. A diferença é que o `==` faz conversão de tipo. Por exemplo:

```
1 == '1': true
1 === '1': false
```

Como você usa string comparando com string não precisa de converter tipo
ficaria:

```
'w' === 'w': true
```