# O que é uma Linguagem de Prototipação?

Tags: python, terminologia, característica-linguagem, prototipação

Lendo um artigo na internet, deparei-me com o seguinte trecho:

> Python, por sua proposta mais generalista, é uma ótima escolha como
>   **linguagem para prototipação** de sistemas construídos em linguagens, digamos, mais burocráticas como C, C++, C# ou Java. Mas, vale lembrar,
>   o Python pode ser utilizado sozinho, como a linguagem escolhida para o
>   desenvolvimento de um grande sistema, web ou desktop. Por ser simples
>   e de propósito geral, é também uma ótima linguagem para o aprendizado
>   de programação, onde o aluno pode aprender diretamente lógica de
>   programação sem perder muito tempo com as já ditas ‘burocracias’ das
>   linguagens acima.

Fonte: [Outerspace (mirror)](http://forum.outerspace.com.br/index.php?threads/linguagens-de-programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o-que-voc%C3%AA-deveria-aprender.353778/)

Meu questionamento é: o que seria uma `linguagem de prototipação`?

Comment: Uma linguagem que você usa para construir um protótipo? É isso que entendi do texto.

Comment: Prototipação é um método de construir software, onde se coloca apenas as funcionalidades basicas, para validação dos  requisitos pelo cliente, se estiver ok o sistema pode ser construido de 'verdade' ou o prototipo pode ser incrementado para o sistema 'final' ou todo esse código pode ser jogado fora.

Comment: E JavaScript? No mesmo artigo, encontrei o seguinte trecho: "JavaScript é uma linguagem orientada a objetos baseada em protótipo." Seria o mesmo sentido para linguagem de prototipação ou são coisas distintas? Devo reformular minha pergunta?

Comment: Vejo que são dois sentidos diferentes, até algum tempo atrás js não tinha classes então tudo é ainda baseado prototipos. Relacionado: [Como funcionam protótipos em JavaScript?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15239/91)

Comment: Eu achei um pouco confuso, vou ler mais a respeito disso. Obrigado @rray

Comment: @rray Mesmo agora tendo "classes", JS continua baseado em protótipos. As classes não são "de verdade", são açúcar sintático. *Under the hood* é só protótipo.

Comment: @bfavaretto, então qual é o sentido de ter "classes" agora em JS?

Comment: Sobre o python, a grosso modo foi dito, python é uma boa opção para criar sistemas descartaveis mas pode ser usado na construção de sistemas não descartaveis.

Comment: @Duds Uma coisa é "construir um protótipo" [de um software], ou "prototipar" [um software]. O texto que você citou fala desse sentido de "protótipo". Já no JavaScript, "protótipo" é um conceito usado no funcionamento da linguagem em si. Os objetos têm acesso a seus "protótipos", que têm funcionalidades extras. Quando você faz `"a,b,c".split(',')"`, a função `split` vem do protótipo de `String`. Sobre as classes é o que eu disse, é açúcar sintático, pra facilitar a escrita do código por quem está mais familiarizado com o paradigma de OOP.

Comment: @rray Traduziu bem. E é uma frase infeliz do autor do texto, porque não quer dizer nada. "Serve pra isso, mas também pra não-isso". Logo, serve pra qualquer coisa! :P

Comment: Entendi, muito a explicação @bfavaretto!

Comment: Se alguem ver, aquele comentário será sinalizado como ofensivo :D @bfavaretto haha

Comment: @bigown, está ok, não é preciso ser melhorado.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

O termo como colocado na pergunta eu desconheço, é possível, mas não conheço nenhuma linguagem que seja especificamente para isso.

Uma linguagem que pode ser usada para prototipar é aquela que tem pouca cerimônia, que permite escrever um código rapidamente apenas pra ver um resultado, testar uma teoria, sem preocupação com performance, se está tudo correto e pronto para uso definitivo. Qualquer linguagem que permita escrever de forma mais simples e com produtividade pode ser considerada uma linguagem adequada para prototipação.

Algumas pessoas irão dizer que qualquer linguagem pode ser usada para isso e eventualmente pode até ser melhor usar a linguagem que será usada em definitivo. Nem sempre o que se faz no protótipo poderá ser reproduzido em outra linguagem. Claro que isso pode ser contornado ou mesmo pode não ser um problema, se a pessoa sabe prototipar.

O ganho em usar um linguagem mais simples pode ser vantajoso ou não. Normalmente esse ganho é pequeno perto do todo.

Prototipação raramente é usada na maioria das aplicações. Em alguns casos, acertadamente, em outros provavelmente evitaria erros detectáveis no protótipo.

Python publicamente vende a ideia de ser uma linguagem para prototipação. Mas ela não tem nada de especial que torne isso melhor. Ela apenas tem pouca cerimônia, como outras com filosofia semelhante. Obviamente reduzir a linguagem a só isso também não faria sentido. Ela permite fazer muito mais que apenas protótipos.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Ter pouca cerimônia é uma das grandes qualidades de Python, que tem muitos usos. Imagino que os pythonistas devem achar ofensivo chamá-la de "linguagem para prototipação"...

Comment: Eles até vendem muito essa ideia. Claro que ela não é só para isto. Na verdade, isto é bem secundário. E como eu disse, qualquer linguagem que não seja muito baixo nível, é para prototipação, se a pessoa souber o que está fazendo.

Answer (score -2):

Uma linguagem de prototipação é uma linguagem de programação usada principalmente para desenvolver protótipos de software.

O principal objetivo de uma linguagem de prototipação é permitir que os desenvolvedores criem rapidamente modelos funcionais ou avançados de um sistema, aplicativo ou recurso antes de passar para a implementação completa.