# Qual é a diferença entre criar um objeto a partir da forma literal ou a partir de uma função construtora?

Tags: javascript, característica-linguagem, objetos, construtor, protótipo

Eu gostaria de saber se possui alguma diferença ou relevância entre as duas formas abaixo na construção de um objeto:

Criar um objeto a partir da forma literal:

```js
let pessoa = {
   nome: 'Pedro'
};

console.log(pessoa.nome);
```

Criar um objeto a partir de uma função construtora:

```js
let pessoa = new Person();

function Person() {
    this.nome = 'Pedro';
}

console.log(pessoa.nome);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Em resumo, a diferença está na forma como os objetos são criados e, portanto, o construtor dos objetos.

---

No seu primeiro exemplo:

```js
let pessoa = {
   nome: 'Pedro'
};

console.log(pessoa.nome);
```

Você simplesmente está criando um novo objeto através de sua notação literal. Você está atribuindo uma propriedade `name` diretamente através dessa notação. Não há nada de muito especial além disso.

No seu segundo exemplo:

```js
function Person() {
    this.nome = 'Pedro';
}

let pessoa = new Person();
console.log(pessoa.nome);
```

Você está *instanciando* um novo objeto do construtor `Person`, ou seja, você está criando um novo objeto do "tipo" `Person`.

Há, então, a diferença, já que quando você usa o operador [`new`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new), o objeto retornado (instanciado) irá herdar o `prototype` de sua função construtora. No seu exemplo, pode-se notar a diferença com o seguinte exemplo:

```js
const person1 = {
  name: 'Luiz'
};

function Person() {
  this.name = 'Luiz';
}

const person2 = new Person();

console.log(person1.constructor.name); // "Object"
console.log(person2.constructor.name); // "Person"
```

Assim, pode-se concluir que, basicamente, a diferença é esta:

- No seu primeiro exemplo, como o objeto está sendo construído usando a sua notação *literal*, ele irá herdar o protótipo do construtor [`Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) (padrão para objetos literais).
- No segundo exemplo, contudo, utiliza-se o construtor `Person`, uma função criada pelo próprio programador. Aí está a diferença.

Isso tudo está muito ligado ao funcionamento de protótipos no JavaScript. Para saber mais, leia [esta outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15239/69296).

---

A título de curiosidade, se você quiser criar um objeto que não possua nenhum parente herdado, você pode utilizar [`Object.create(null)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create), sendo o primeiro argumento o protótipo que o objeto a ser criado herdará.

```js
const example1 = {};
const example2 = Object.create(null);

console.log(example1.constructor.name); // "Object"
console.log(example2.constructor); // undefined
```

Comment: Agora fiquei mais confuso ainda, estou aprendendo sobre OOJS e não entendo muito sobre protótipo, construtor, herdar, polimorfismo, etc eu vou dar mais uma estudada sobre esses conceitos, assim quando eu voltar a rever essa resposta estará mais clara para mim, valeu! :)

Comment: @felipecardozo Sobre protótipo, um bom ponto de partida é aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15239/112052

Comment: @hkotsubo, obrigado! por compartilhar o link da resposta vou dar uma lida.