# Criação de objetos em JavaScript

Tags: javascript, objetos, construtor

Digamos que queremos criar um objeto chamado `Retângulo` (se desejar, com propriedades como comprimento, largura, perímetro e área). Conforme mostrado no próximo diagrama (criado com base nas informações presentes [neste link](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/js10-objects/topics/javascript-objects)), podemos criar objetos usando pelo menos duas maneiras diferentes

1. Inicializadores de objeto (Object initializers)
2. Funções de construtor (Constructor functions)

[image: Criar objetos em JavaScript]

Então, dentro dos inicializadores de objetos, há pelo menos três maneiras diferentes para criar.

Entendo que, à primeira vista, o uso da função construtora exigirá escrever a função e só então inicializá-la. Algo como

```
function Rectangle(a, b) {
    this.length = a;
    this.width = b;
    this.perimeter = 2 * (a+b);
    this.area = a * b;
}
```

e depois usar

```
const rec = new Rectangle(a, b);
```

Embora possa parecer um trabalho extra, quando queremos usar as funções de construtor? Além disso, é irrelevante se inicializarmos com o `new Rectangle()`, `Rectangle.create()` ou `var Rectangle = {}`?

Comment: Alguma destas respostas responde à sua pergunta? [Diferença entre função construtora e função que retorna objeto literal](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/454788/diferen%c3%a7a-entre-fun%c3%a7%c3%a3o-construtora-e-fun%c3%a7%c3%a3o-que-retorna-objeto-literal) ou [Qual é a diferença entre criar um objeto a partir da forma literal ou a partir de uma função construtora?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/445939/qual-%c3%a9-a-diferen%c3%a7a-entre-criar-um-objeto-a-partir-da-forma-literal-ou-a-partir-d)

Comment: Diria que não @LuizFelipe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Há uma enorme diferença entre os 3.

Quando você cria o objeto através do construtor este é chamado e é aquele código que criará o objeto da forma como ele foi escrito. Talvez queira saber mais sobre em [Para que serve um construtor?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/101).

O segundo chama uma função padrão que todo objeto de JS tem, que é a função [`create()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create). Ela funciona como uma espécie de construtor quando não há ou não usa o construtor escrito especificamente para um tipo de objeto. Ele faz o melhor esforço para criar um objeto daquele tipo que faça sentido. Algumas propriedades do objeto podem ser inicializadas com os valores já declarados na definição do protótipo do objeto.

A terceira forma sequer tem uma informação que objeto está criando, apenas que está criando um objeto e ele será essencialmente vazio (tem o que todo objeto já tem em JS). Você poderá adicionar membros dentro dele depois ou até mudar completamente esse objeto. Na verdade, pelo menos no código mostrado, está criando uma vaiável chamada `Rectangle` que nada tem a ver com o objeto que quer definir.

Na maioria das vezes o construtor é a forma mais correta, especialmente se ele existe que se tornaria quase obrigatório.