# Por que o "this" é necessário na função construtora

Tags: javascript, funções, objetos

Gostaria de entender o motivo de o "this" ser necessário dentro de uma função construtora. Ele não deveria ser necessário somente após criar o objeto?
Exemplo abaixo:

```
function Data(dia = 1, mes = 1, ano = 1) {
  this.dia = dia;
  this.mes = mes;
  this.ano = ano;

  this.exibir = function() {
      return `${this.dia}/${this.mes}/${this.ano}`;
  }
}
```

Comment: Quando a função é usada com um construtor sua propriedade [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#como_um_construtor_(constructor)) é vinculada ao novo objeto sendo construído.

Comment: Não é necessário para o "construtor", é "necessário" para  a sua necessidade especifica de passar os valores dos parâmetros para serem acessadas pelos métodos. Apesar que da forma que você criou o método `exibir()`, nem precisaria, já que `dia`, `mes` e `ano` (sem o `this.`) são acessíveis por ele. Resumindo, this é só necessário no construtor conforme a sua necessidade. Rodrigo e @AugustoVasques, talvez amanhã, isso se ninguém tiver feito uma resposta explicando de fato isso.

Comment: O valor do `this` dentro de uma função varia de acordo com a forma como a função é chamada. Se ela é chamada como um construtor (ou seja, com `new`), o `this` passa a ser a instância sendo construída. Então não é que "precisa" ser assim, na verdade vc avalia como a função vai ser usada e o que precisa fazer, e vê se usar `this` é o mais adequado para cada caso. Ver mais [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/445939/112052) e [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#this_in_function_contexts)

Answer (score -2):

O this faz referencia ao próprio objeto.

Quando você digita:

```
this.dia = dia;
```

você está criando um atributo dia para seu objeto e esta salvando o valor de dia neste atributo.

Apos o objeto criado, você não usará mais o "this" e sim a instancia do Objeto, exemplos:

```
function Data(dia = 1, mes = 1, ano = 1) {
    this.dia = dia;
    this.mes = mes;
    this.ano = ano;

    this.exibir = function() {
        return `${this.dia}/${this.mes}/${this.ano}`;
    }
}

var isntancia = new Data()
console.log(isntancia.dia)
```