# O que é Prototype Pollution?

Tags: javascript, segurança, objetos, protótipo

Utilizo uma ferramenta que realiza checagens de segurança nos pacotes do meu projeto, a mesma me indicou que um dos pacotes é suscetível a **Prototype Pollution**, gostaria de saber:

- O que é exatamente Prototype Pollution?
- Consigo verificar se meu
  código é suscetível sem uso de bibliotecas externas?
- Como faço para
  evitar que o meu código seja vulnerável?

Comment: Relacionado: [Como funcionam protótipos em JavaScript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15239/como-funcionam-prot%c3%b3tipos-em-javascriptT)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Antes de tudo, vale entender minimamente o que são os protótipos em JavaScript. Basicamente, todo objeto em JavaScript pode herdar propriedades e métodos da [cadeia de protótipos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/15247/69296).

Primitivos, por sua vez, não são objetos e, portanto, não têm propriedades, mas, em face de algo chamado "*[primitive wrapping](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Glossario/Primitivo#Wrappers_em_JavaScript)*", possuem associações com os objetos correspondentes. Por exemplo, o primitivo `string` é envolvido pelo construtor `String`; primitivo `number`, por `Number` e por aí vai. É por isso que, apesar de primitivos não possuirem propriedades, você pode, na prática, acessar propriedades em "valores primitivos".

---

### Modificando `__proto__`

A poluição de protótipos (*prototype pollution*), em resumo, acontece quando você modifica o protótipo de um valor, o que irá refletir na mudança de todos os outros valores que compartilham o mesmo protótipo. Veja um exemplo:

```js
const obj1 = { name: 'Foo' };
const obj2 = { name: 'Bar' };

console.log(obj1.changed); // undefined
console.log(obj2.changed); // undefined

obj1.__proto__.changed = true;

console.log(obj1.changed); // true
console.log(obj2.changed); // true

const obj3 = { name: 'Baz' };
const str1 = 'Qux';

console.log(obj3.changed); // true
console.log(str1.changed); // true
```

<sup>No exemplo acima, utilizei a propriedade `__proto__` (presente em todos os objetos) para acessar e alterar o protótipo de um dado objeto. Atualmente, a linguagem também oferece outros mecanismos para fazer isso, como `Reflect.getPrototypeOf` e `Reflect.setPrototypeOf`. Em virtude do fato de `__proto__` estar presente em todos os objetos da linguagem, torna-se trivial alterar (muitas vezes não intencionalmente) o protótipo de certo objeto.</sup>

Note que, ao alterar o objeto `__proto__`, você altera está alterando o protótipo do objeto que o contém. No exemplo acima, estamos modificando o objeto `Object.prototype` (que é o protótipo do objeto literal que criamos).

Observe também que, como os protótipos formam uma cadeia, ao modificar `Object.prototype`, praticamente todos os valores do JavaScript também terão sido invadidos, uma vez que praticamente tudo estende `Object` (exceto `null` e `undefined`). Isso acontece porque, ao contrário de primitivos, em JavaScript, objetos são passados por **referência**. Assim, como o protótipo de um dado objeto é frequentemente compartilhado (por referência) entre diversos outros objetos ("instâncias"), você acabará por, provavelmente, alterar algo que não era para ser modificado, já que as alterações, nesse caso, *não são locais*, mas sim globais entre todos os valores que compartilham aquela referência.

Essa vulnerabilidade é muito comum em operações de fusão (*merge*), clonagem (*clone*), atribuição via caminho (*path assignment*) ou extensão (*extend*) de objetos.

Note que, `<obj>.__proto__` permite acesso direto à propriedade `prototype` do construtor de um dado objeto. Você também pode acessá-lo (e modificá-lo) via `<obj>.constructor.prototype`. Saiba mais sobre a propriedade [`constructor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/Constructor) aqui. Para constar, ao contrário de `__proto__`, a propriedade `construtor` [está especificada](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/11.0/index.html#sec-object.prototype.constructor).

Se você está trabalhando com objetos de forma dinâmica, deverá, então, garantir que modificará a propriedade `__proto__` ou `constructor` por engano, que podem ser utilizadas como meio para esse tipo de ataque. Você também pode utilizar o método [`hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/HasOwnProperty) para garantir que não está utilizando propriedades herdadas da cadeia de protótipos.

<sup>Está longe de ser uma boa solução para o problema, mas é interessante comentar que há como desativar ou impedir o uso de `__proto__` no Node.js através da *flag* [`--disable-proto`](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_disable_proto_mode).</sup>

---

### Extensão de objetos nativos (*constructor augmentation*)

Uma outra forma muito comum de *prototype pollution* é modificar a propriedade `prototype` de um construtor. Nesse caso também pode ser chamado de *prototype augmentation*, já que é intencional.

Por exemplo, o JavaScript não possui o método `Array.prototype.shuffle` (para embaralhar um array). Com isso, ao invés de se criar uma **função** `shuffle`, anexa-se um **novo** e **não padronizado** método no próprio protótipo dos arrays. Assim:

```js
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'shuffle', {
  writable: true,
  configurable: true,
  enumerable: false,
  value: function() {
    // Implementação qualquer.
    console.log('Chamado Array.prototype.shuffle em:', this);
  }
});

[1, 2, 3].shuffle();
```

A princípio, isso pode parecer uma boa ideia, já que fica sintaticamente mais agradável. É muito mais bonito fazer `[1, 2, 3].shuffle` do que `shuffle([1, 2, 3])` — pelo menos muita gente parece achar. No entanto, isso pode trazer uma série de consequências negativas:

1. #### Possível interferência entre códigos

   No caso dessa prática se tornar comum, nada garante que uma biblioteca A poderá estender ou modificar o que uma biblioteca B já modificou.
2. #### Quebra de compatibilidade a longo prazo

   Se muita gente decidir estender um objeto nativo, duas situações ruins podem emergir:

   - A especificação estandardizar o novo método e todo o código que modificou ficará com a implementação não oficial, que é, indubitavelmente, menos performática.
   - A especificação simplesmente não ser capaz de criar um novo método. Isso aconteceu com o `Array.prototype.contains` (nome original que, para não quebrar compatibilidade, teve que ser trocado para `Array.prototype.includes`). <sub>[[Ref]](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-Array.prototype.includes#status)</sub>
3. #### Alterar o resultado do `for..in`

   Muitas pessoas usam o `for..in` para iterar sobre as propriedades de certo objeto. Como esse laço também leva em conta as propriedades herdadas pelo protótipo (propriedades não próprias), se a pessoa não tomar o mínimo cuidado ao estendê-lo, poderá afetar os laços `for..in`. Veja:

   ```js
   const arr = ['a', 'b'];

   // Antes de estender `Array.prototype`:
   for (const key in arr) {
     console.log(key, '->', arr[key]);
   }

   console.log('----');

   // Estendendo o protótipo de `Array` (forma leviana):
   Array.prototype.shuffle = function() {
     // Implementação qualquer.
     console.log('Chamado Array.prototype.shuffle em:', this);
   }

   // Depois da extensão.
   for (const key in arr) {
     console.log(key, '->', arr[key]);
   }
   ```

   Por conta disso, no caso de se estender um objeto nativo do JavaScript, é recomendado utilizar o método `Object.defineProperty` para criar a nova propriedade com o atributo `[[Enumerable]]` definido como `false`, visando à não alteração do comportamento padrão do `for..in`. [Saiba mais sobre descritores e atributos de propriedade aqui.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/478412/69296)

Em suma, só modifique o código se você tiver certeza do que está fazendo. Em pequena escala, o problema não será tão alarmante, mas nessas condições vale questionar: será que realmente vale a pena? Na maioria das vezes uma função já basta.