# Como evitar chamadas duplicadas de addEventListener em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, javascript-eventos

Gostaria de adicionar um evento a várias classes diferentes, exemplo:

```
exemplo1.addEventListener('click', function(){
    //Evento bla bla
});

exemplo2.addEventListener('click', function(){
    //Evento bla bla
});

exemplo3.addEventListener('click', function(){
    //Evento bla bla
});
```

E para não criar código duplicado, gostaria de transformar esse *event* em algo como:

```
exemplo1.eventExample();
exemplo2.eventExample();
exemplo3.eventExample();
```

Este `eventExample` teria o:

```
addEventListener('click', function(){
    //Evento bla bla
});
```

Peço perdão se utilizei de algum termo errado, estou iniciando na programação!

Eu sei que poderia criar uma função com o mesmo código do evento e jogar dentro dos outros *event listeners*, mas queria aprender dessa maneira.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se você adicionar ouvintes de evento no JavaScript, há de adicionar um por vez. Pois não existe `addEventListeners`, somente `addEventListener` (no singular).

Essa duplicação raramente é problemática, mas se você realmente quiser se livrar dela, pode criar um array com os elementos a receberem o *listener* e iterar sobre eles, adicionando individualmente em uma única linha. A ressalva é que você compartilhará o mesmo *handler* entre todos eles, mas esse parece ser o requisito da pergunta.

Algo assim:

```
function eventHandler(event) {
  // Faça algo aqui.
}

[example1, example2, example3].forEach((example) =>
  example.addEventListener('click', eventHandler));
```

Veja um exemplo funcional:

```js
const el1 = document.getElementById('el-1');
const el2 = document.getElementById('el-2');

function eventHandler(event) {
  console.log('Clicou em:', event.currentTarget.textContent);
}

[el1, el2].forEach((el) =>
  el.addEventListener('click', eventHandler));
```

```html
<a href="#" id="el-1">Clique! (a tag)</a>
<button id="el-2">Clique! (button tag)</button>
```

Você também pode encontrar por aí "recomendações" para modificar o `prototype` de `NodeList` (ou construtor similar) visando à adição de um novo método (como `addEventListeners`), mas isso raramente é necessário e sequer é boa ideia, já que pode trazer problemas. [Explico-os em mais detalhes aqui.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/449752/69296)