# Como a alteração do prototype do método String.prototype.toString() afeta esse código em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, string, característica-linguagem, objetos, protótipo

Não consegui entender porquê o método `reverse` é aplicado na string `"abcde"` (sobre-escrito em `toString`) e não em `"12345"`.

```js
String.prototype.reverse = function() {
    return this.split('').reverse().join('');
}

String.prototype.toString = function() {
    return 'abcde';
}

console.log('12345'.reverse());
```

Comment: Ah, o Javascript é uma caixinha de surpresas! Mas é por essa e outras que não é recomendável alterar o `prototype` de um tipo nativo em Javascript.

Comment: Eu dei +1. Acho a dúvida válida.

Comment: Fiz uns testes. Aparentemente, esse problema só ocorre com novos métodos adicionados ao `String.prototype`. Não sei por qual motivo, mas, dentro do escopo do método criado via `prototype`, é considerado o `toString` modificado ao invés do valor original.

Comment: Vou relacionar [O que é Prototype Pollution](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/449732/o-que-%c3%a9-prototype-pollution/449752#449752) e [Como funcionam os prototipos em Javascript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15239/como-funcionam-prot%c3%b3tipos-em-javascript/15247#15247)

Comment: @WallaceMaxters, vou na sua esteira. Mas não ao ponto de dar um up(só tirar o down) essa sobrescrição de métodos na cadeia de protótipos de objetos nativos me dá arrepios.

Comment: Eu entendo que essa sobrescrição não é algo que deva ser feito, pois pode afetar o código de maneiras imprevisíveis, como ocorreu. Mas não vejo problemas em explorar a linguagem e aumentar o conhecimento sobre como ela opera.

Comment: Se é por motivo de curiosidade eu não tenho problemas. Como recebemos perguntas de usuários com nível de conhecimento variável fica difícil saber se o usuário  só está brincando com a linguagem ou se toma o conceito como certo. Se é só isso toma o meu +1.

Comment: Relacionada também: [O que é e como funciona o contexto (this) no JavaScript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/8975/69296)

Answer (score 9):

Isso acontece porque, de acordo com a [especificação](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/11.0/index.html#sec-string.prototype.split), o método `String.prototype.split` converte o valor `this` para string utilizando a operação `ToString`. De acordo com a etapa 3 do algoritmo em questão:

> Let S be ? [ToString](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/11.0/index.html#sec-tostring)(O).

Esse `ToString` (note a letra maiúscula — não é a mesma coisa que `toString`) é uma operação abstrata que acaba, a depender do tipo do parâmetro, chamando a implementação `toString`. No caso de objetos, a operação abstrata `ToString` acabará executando a implementação `toString` do `this` utilizado.

No seu caso, o `this` trata-se de objeto porque, quando você passa o `this` dentro da sua implementação de `String.prototype.reverse`, o `this` (que *era* um primitivo string) está sendo convertido ao objeto `String` correspondente.

Essa conversão feita pelo algoritmo pode vir a ser "útil" quando passa-se uma não string como o `this` de `split`, mas que implementa `toString`. Um exemplo:

```js
const result = String.prototype.split.call(
  { // Objeto que implementa `toString` ("argumento" `this` de `split`).
    toString() {
      return '1-2-3';
    }
  },
  '-' // Separador (1º argumento de `split`).
);

console.log(result); //=> ['1', '2', '3']
```

Não sei porque alguém faria algo assim. Acho que a necessidade desse comportamento está mais intrinsecamente ligada à natureza de coerções automáticas do JavaScript. Enfim, a própria especificação assegura essa genericidade para o método `split`:

> The `split` function is intentionally generic; it does not require that its `this` value be a String object. Therefore, it can be transferred to other kinds of objects for use as a method.

Em tradução livre: A função `split` é intencionalmente genérica; ela não requer que seu valor `this` seja um objeto String. Desse modo, pode ser transferida a outros tipos de objeto para uso como método.

### Modo estrito?

Mais uma variante para tornar o JavaScript ainda mais confuso! :')

Observe que a conversão ao objeto no `this` só é feita no "modo normal" de execução do JavaScript. Se o código estiver rodando no [modo estrito](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/3752/69296), esse comportamento **não** ocorrerá e o `split` utilizará o valor primitivo do `this` (portanto, a implementação sobre-escrita de `toString` não será levada em conta). Veja o seu código rodando no modo estrito:

```js
'use strict';

String.prototype.reverse = function() {
  // Como está rodando em modo estrito, este `this`
  // não será convertido em objeto e, portanto,
  // o valor literal será utilizado pelo método `split`.
  return this.split('').reverse().join('');
}

String.prototype.toString = function() {
  return 'abcde';
}

console.log('12345'.reverse()); // Utilizou `12345`. Saída: `54321`.
```

---

<sup><sup>O JavaScript é confuso e essa situação é só mais uma prova disso.</sup></sup>

Answer (score 4):

Todo objeto pode ser convertido para um representação textual dele. Isto é feito com a função `toString()`. Todos os os tipos possuem isso, sem exceção.

Você pode estar pensando, mas um tipo `String`, já é uma *string*, então não tem porque converter. Pode ser, mas a função está presente para entregar a representação textual do objeto. Até porque a forma como essa *string* é organizada internamente no objeto não é problema seu, é problema exclusive do objeto, é detalhe de implementação, só a função `toString()` garante que entregará uma representação textual de algo, só ela permite você mostrar um texto de um objeto, inclusive em objeto do tipo `String`.

E deve imaginar que em várias situações essa função `toString()` é chamada implicitamente para obter o resultado desejado, por exemplo no `console.log()` que sua função é imprimir a representação textual de um objeto. Essa função não imprime detalhes de implementação de nenhum objeto, só a representação textual, até mesmo de um número, não está imprimindo o número só o texto que representa aquele número. Há outras situações que essa função é chamada, e em JavaScript isso chega ser bem confuso, mas não vem ao caso aqui.

Sempre que for pegar o valor do objeto onde se espera um texto a função será chamada. `reverse()` espera um texto, então na prática o que está acontecendo ali no código é, a grosso modo:

```
console.log('Escola Cod3r'.toString().reverse());
```

Da mesma forma que teria que fazer isto:

```
console.log(123..toString().reverse());
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Object/Prototype.js).

Note que JS tende a querer transformar boa parte do objetos em texto, isso pode ser confuso.

E é o resultado que é obtido. Não tem nada de extraordinário, isso é o certo a fazer por uma questão de manter tudo linear, ou seja, pra que tratar o tipo `String` como especial? Se tudo precisa ser assim, que seja assim.

Temos mais um fã de não por ponto e vírgula que vai sofrer com as confusões do JS.