# Como faço para exibir uma variável do tipo object na tela através do alert?

Tags: javascript

No alert aparece a seguinte mensagem: [object Object]

Segue código abaixo:

```
let carro = {
    modelo: "corsa",
    marca: "chevrolet",
    aVenda: true
};

alert(carro);
```

Answer (score 3):

Para mostrar a estrutura do objeto como texto, você pode utilizar a função `JSON.stringify`, segue um exemplo abaixo:

```js
let carro = {
    modelo: "corsa",
    marca: "chevrolet",
    aVenda: true
};

alert(JSON.stringify(carro));
```

Caso contrário, o alert mostra apenas o tipo da variável, que no caso, é um object. O que o `JSON.stringify` faz nesse caso é deserializar o objeto para uma string contendo as propriedades e valores do objeto.

Answer (score 3):

De acordo com a documentação, o método [`Window.alert`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Window/alert) possui um argumento `message`, que:

> `message` é uma string opcional com o texto que você quer exibir na caixa de diálogo, ou, ainda, um objeto a ser convertido em string e exibido.

Desse modo, quando você fornecer algo que não é uma string para esse argumento, o método usará o método `toString` do valor passado para tentar representá-lo no formato textual.

Assim, tendo em vista que, por padrão, o método [`toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/ToString) de um objeto (herdado, através da [cadeia de protótipos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/15247/69296), do construtor [`Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object)), retorna `[object Object]`, você não pode utilizar essa conversão implícita.

Uma opção, conforme sugerido pelo [Marcell Alves na outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/460499/69296), é utilizar o método [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify), que serializa um objeto em JavaScript para a sua representação no formato JSON (que é, basicamente, uma string):

```js
const carro = {
  modelo: "corsa",
  marca: "chevrolet",
  aVenda: true
};

alert(JSON.stringify(carro));
```

Uma outra opção é sobrescrever o método `toString` do objeto, de modo que a conversão implícita seja feita de acordo com um formato pré-definido por você:

```js
const carro = {
  modelo: "Corsa",
  marca: "Chevrolet",
  aVenda: true,
  
  // Sobrescrita do método `toString`:
  toString() {
    return `Carro ${this.modelo} ${this.marca}.` + (this.aVenda ? ' À venda' : '');
  }
};

alert(carro);
```