# Aplicar propriedades iguais para diferentes objetos em JS

Tags: javascript, objetos

Eu gostaria de saber como faço para encapsular propriedades idênticas que estão sendo atribuídas a diferentes objetos. Por exemplo:

No meu código, existe um objeto 'first', que se localiza dentro de uma classe, e possui uma propriedade chamada 'redirection', cuja esta também está em outros objetos, como 'second' e 'third'. Eu gostaria de saber como faço, de uma vez só, para aplicar esta mesma propriedade em todos estes objetos de uma só vez, como é comum no CSS, por exemplo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim é possível nativamente fazer com que diferentes instancias em *javascript* possam ter uma ou mais propriedades vinculadas de forma que a alteração de uma dessas propriedades vinculadas em qualquer uma das instancias coordenadas se reflita por todas as outras.

É um padrão de projeto chamado [Binding Properties Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binding_properties_pattern). Esse padrão é normalmente utilizado em código concorrente mas pode ser utilizado em código single thread. Esse padrão deriva do paradigma de [Programação Orientada a Aspectos](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o_orientada_a_aspecto).

O padrão original consiste em combinar vários [observers](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer), padrão esse que define uma dependência um-para-muitos entre objetos de modo que quando um objeto muda o estado seus dependentes são notificados, de forma a forçar que propriedades em diferentes objetos a se coordenarem.

No caso por conta da linguagem ser [orientada a protótipos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15239/como-funcionam-prot%C3%B3tipos-em-javascript) e ser de thread único me permite fazer uma simplificação no padrão *Binding Properties* onde ao invés de o implementar baseado em observers posso o implementar sobre um padrão de [Proxy](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_(padr%C3%B5es_de_projeto)).

Proxy nada mais é que um objeto que controla o acesso a outro, aqui desempenhará o papel do observer no padrão *Binding Properties*, porém ao invés de notificar um evento ele irá fazer uma modificação direta no objeto proxiado.

> OBS: Caso o código seja aplicado em objetos encapsulado em diferentes [Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Worker) a implementação original com Observer pattern deve ser retomada.

Em javascript o padrão de projeto proxy é implementado pela [interface nativa Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy).

O algoritmo é simples:

- Primeiro define-se três classe distintas usando [funções construtoras](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-PT/docs/Javascript_orientado_a_objetos#fun.c3.a7.c3.a3o_construtora_e_propriedades_.2f_classe_e_atributos).
- Em seguida as classes são instanciadas e por atribuição [via desestruturação](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Atribuicao_via_desestruturacao) suas referências são ligadas as suas respectivas variáveis identificadoras.
- É feito um log das propriedades `redirection` de cada uma uma dessas instâncias.
- É criado o handler para o proxy:

  ```
  const BindingPatternHandler = {
    //Conjunto dos objetos dependentes.
    targets: new Set(),          
    //Disparado no proxy a qualquer alteração em suas propriedades.                  
    set: function(self, prop, value, receiver) {
            //Se a propriedade modificada for 'redirection'...
            if (prop === 'redirection'){
                //...para cada um dos objetos proxiados..
                for (let target of this.targets){
                    target.redirection = value       //...repassa a modificação.
                }
            }
    }
  }
  ```
- É criada a função que aplica o padrão a dada instância:

  ```
  //Cria o proxy para o objeto e o coloca como dependente do proxy.
  function bindingPattern(obj){
    BindingPatternHandler.targets.add(obj);
    return new Proxy(f, BindingPatternHandler);
  }
  ```
- É aplicado o as três instancias previamente criadas.
- E então são feitos três testes simples onde é demonstrado que ao modificar a propriedade `redirection` em qualquer uma das instâncias proxiadas todas as outras instâncias proxiadas também terão a propriedade `redirection` modificada com o mesmo valor.

**Solução:**

```js
//Define três classes distintas.  
const First = function(){
   this.redirection="First";
};

const Second = function(){
   this.redirection="Second";
};

const Third = function(){
   this.redirection="Third";
};

//Instancia três objetos das classes anteriormente declaradas.
let [f, s, t] =[new First(), new Second(), new Third()];

//Loga as propriedades ainda não sincronizadas.
console.log('Valores de redirection antes de aplicar Binding Pattern');
console.log([f.redirection,s.redirection,t.redirection]);

const BindingPatternHandler = {        
    targets: new Set(),
    set: function(self, prop, value, receiver) {                
            if (prop === 'redirection'){                    
                for (let target of this.targets){
                    target.redirection = value;       
                }
            }
    }
}

function bindingPattern(obj){
    BindingPatternHandler.targets.add(obj);
    return new Proxy(f, BindingPatternHandler);
}

//Aplica o padrão as instancias "f", "s" e "t".
[f, s, t] = [f, s, t].map(bindingPattern);

//Realiza os testes de coordenação das propriedades.
console.log('Teste nº 1 do Binding Pattern: f.redirection = "teste1"');
f.redirection = "teste1";
console.log([f.redirection,s.redirection,t.redirection]);

console.log('Teste nº 2 do Binding Pattern: s.redirection = "teste2";');
s.redirection = "teste2";
console.log([f.redirection,s.redirection,t.redirection]);

console.log('Teste nº 3 do Binding Pattern: t.redirection = "teste3";');
t.redirection = "teste3";
console.log([f.redirection,s.redirection,t.redirection]);
```

Answer (score -1):

Até onde vai meu conhecimento atualmente, não há uma forma nativa de fazer isso no JS.

O que pode ser feito é criar uma função auxiliar que cria uma propriedade com um valor em objetos passados como argumento para essa função:

```js
function inserePropriedadeComValorNoObjeto(objeto, propriedade, valor) {
 objeto[propriedade] = valor;
}
```

A partir disso, você pode chamar a função passando o que precisa em um laço de repetição `forEach` em um array, apenas como um exemplo:

```js
arrayDeObjetos.forEach(objeto => { 
  inserePropriedadeComValorNoObjeto(objeto, 'redirection', 'valor')
})
```

Também é possível trocar `forEach` por `map` e retornar um novo array de objetos com as propriedades que desejar, basta retornar o objeto da função `inserePropriedade...` após inserir a propriedade, como `return objeto` no final dela:

```js
const novoArrayDeObjetosComPropriedadeRedirection = arrayDeObjetos.map(objeto => inserePropriedadeComValorNoObjeto(objeto, 'redirection', 'valor'))
```

Sua função ficaria:

```js
function inserePropriedadeComValorNoObjeto(objeto, propriedade, valor) {
  objeto[propriedade] = valor;
  return objeto;
}
```

Se preferir, pode chamar a função para cada objeto manualmente sem o uso do `return`. A função vai inserir uma propriedade no objeto que passou como argumento, alterando-o por referência.

Espero ter ajudado de alguma forma.

Comment: Entendi bro. Muito bem explicado. Parabéns pelo conhecimento.