# Por que, quando não uso "this", o método não reflete alterações feitas ao objeto?

Tags: javascript, classes

```js
class Endereco {
  constructor(Rua, Cidade, CEP) {
    this.Rua = Rua;
    this.Cidade = Cidade;
    this.CEP = CEP;
    this.exibirEndereco = function() {
      console.log(`Endereço: Rua ${Rua}, Cidade de ${Cidade}, CEP ${CEP}`);
    };
  }
}

const endereco1 = new Endereco('avenida', 'Sao mateus', '354136-45');

endereco1.exibirEndereco();
endereco1.CEP = 'novo CEP'; // pq nao atualiza o objeto ??
endereco1.exibirEndereco();
```

Por que, mesmo alterando as propriedades da instância, o método não as reflete?

Answer (score 5):

Na verdade, atualiza o objeto sim. Veja:

```js
class Endereco {
  constructor(rua, cidade) {
    this.rua = rua;
    this.cidade = cidade;
    this.exibirEndereco = function() {
      console.log(`Endereço: ${rua}, ${cidade}.`);
    };
  }
}

const avBr = new Endereco('Avenida Brasil', 'Belo Horizonte');
console.log(avBr);

avBr.cidade = 'Rio de Janeiro';
console.log(avBr); // atualizou a propriedade cidade
```

O problema dá-se tendo em vista de onde as variáveis utilizadas pelo método `exibirEndereco` advieram.

Note que, dentro da função `exibirEndereco`, tanto `rua` quanto `cidade` não se referem às propriedades da instância de `Endereco`, mas sim das variáveis paramétricas do construtor.

Portanto, mesmo que você altere as variáveis da instância, a função `exibirEndereco`, criada durante a *construção* do objeto, manterá suas variáveis inalteradas (já que as variáveis que você passou ao construtor não foram alteradas). Lembre-se que primitivos do JavaScript, como `string`, são imutáveis.

Para corrigir esse problema, faça com que o método `exibirEndereco` dependa de variáveis da instância. Você pode acessar essas variáveis sob a qualificação `this` (que, nesse tipo de situação, refere-se à instância).

Uma outra ideia é não declarar o método no construtor, mas sim na própria classe. Veja:

```js
class Endereco {
  constructor(rua, cidade) {
    this.rua = rua;
    this.cidade = cidade;
  }
  
  exibirEndereco() {
    //                       ↓↓↓↓         ↓↓↓↓
    console.log(`Endereço: ${this.rua}, ${this.cidade}.`);
  }
}

const avBr = new Endereco('Avenida Brasil', 'Belo Horizonte');
avBr.exibirEndereco(); // Endereço: Avenida Brasil, Belo Horizonte

avBr.cidade = 'Rio de Janeiro';
avBr.exibirEndereco(); // Endereço: Avenida Brasil, Rio de Janeiro
```

A vantagem dessa forma para se definir o método é que, ao anexar à função ao `this` durante a construção, você gera uma nova função para cada instância. Métodos definidos diretamente na classe associam-se ao protótipo do construtor, sendo, portanto, reutilizados por todas as instâncias. [Saiba mais sobre protótipos aqui.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15239/69296)

Comment: Muito boa a resposta! me tire uma dúvida.. serve apenas para JavaScript? ou está inclusas outras linguagens também?

Comment: Obrigado, @gleisin-dev! :)) Não posso dizer com certeza já que isso é algo que depende muito de cada linguagem… Mas, de modo geral, acho que a diferença entre consumir uma variável paramétrica e uma variável da instância pode sim causar esse tipo de problema em várias linguagens.

Comment: irei me atentar ao declarar esses métodos, principalmente em [tag:php].. vira e meche to apanhando rsrs!