# Nome do construtor sendo exibido no array ao acessá-lo via console

Tags: javascript, array, console, construtor

Estou com uma pequena dúvida, diria até que é mais uma curiosidade, sobre a exibição do nome da função construtora (como se fosse um título) ao acessar no console um array com objetos instanciados por esta função.

Quando adiciono um objeto em um array, e consulto ele no console, tenho seguinte resposta:

```
var biblioteca = [];
biblioteca.push({titulo: “De primatas a astronautas”})
```

Obtenho no console:

```
[{...}]
0: {titulo: “De primatas a astronautas”}
```

E quando adiciono um objeto, criado por uma função construtora, no array e consulto ele no console, tenho como resposta:

```
var biblioteca = [];
var livro = new Livro("De primatas a astronautas");
biblioteca.push(livro);
```

Obtenho no console:

```
[Livro]
0: Livro {titulo: “De primatas a astronautas”}
```

No segundo exemplo, é exibido um “título” com o nome da função construtora (Livro) para o objeto. Este título é exibido somente como uma informação sobre qual foi a função que instanciou aquele objeto?

Sei que é uma dúvida simples, mas é a primeira vez que vejo esta informação sendo exibida assim no console... então fica a dúvida.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O nome no lado do objeto indica que ele tem um construtor, e isso indica que pode haver mais propriedades no objeto, estando no seu protótipo, por exemplo:

> [Como funcionam protótipos em JavaScript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15239/91006)

```js
class Livro {
  constructor(titulo) {
    this.titulo = titulo
  }
  
  qualquerCoisa() {
    return 'Qualquer Coisa';
  }
}

const livro = new Livro('Exemplo');

console.log(livro);
console.log(livro.qualquerCoisa);
console.log(livro.__proto__.qualquerCoisa);
```

Apesar do primeiro `console.log` mostrar apenas a propriedade `titulo`, há também o método `qualquerCoisa`, "escondido" (no sentido que não é mostrado no console diretamente) no seu protótipo

Isso pode ser observado também nas APIs nativas:

```js
const promise = new Promise(() => {});

console.log(promise);
console.log(promise.then);
console.log(promise.__proto__.then);
```

Lembrando que o console é do navegador e o que ele mostra ou não pode variar de acordo com cada implementação. Também há o console do NodeJS que é um pouco diferente

Comment: Muito obrigado!!!

Comment: @Mantuan se respondeu tua pergunta, marque o "v" na resposta pra que a pergunta seja considerada respondida

Comment: Respondeu sim, sou meio novato aqui, não sabia sobre a questão de marcar como respondida. Vou fazer já...